# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1-x \right){{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1+x \right)}{1+x}dx}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, summation

I want to evaluate $$\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1-x \right){{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1+x \right)}{1+x}dx}$$
I run this integral on Maple, It does converge. How we get a closed form?
Is that related to polylogs? $\operatorname{Li}_{5}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1-x \right){{\ln }^{2}}\left( 1+x \right)}{1+x}dx} 
    &=& \left. \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}
\int_0^1 dx\, (1-x)^s(1+x)^{t-1} \right) \right|_{s=t=0} \\
    &=& \left. \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}
\,\frac{{}_2F_1(1-t,1;s+2;-1)}{s+1} \right) \right|_{s=t=0}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
Here we've used Euler's integral representation for the [hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

*Addendum*: 
Using the series representation for the hypergeometric function we can take the derivatives. After a little work we find the integral can be written as
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty  \frac{(-1)^k}{k+1} 
\left(H_k^2 - H_k^{(2)}\right)
\left(H_{k+1}^2 + H_{k+1}^{(2)}\right),$$
where $H_k$ and $H_k^{(n)}$ are the [harmonic and generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), respectively. 
This sum has bad convergence behavior, the terms go like $(-1)^k(\log k)^4/k$ $(k\to\infty)$.
Since the sum is alternating we could accelerate it using the [Euler transform](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerTransform.html), for example.

Comment: Thx! But there should be a nicer form : )

Comment: @Ryan: If it exists someone will post it here. I would be surprised, but I have been before. :-)

Comment: @Chris'ssister : Sure buddy : )

Comment: @Chris'ssister I m sry guys, Actually one of the integral got a missing lnx term :( You can see here (lots of integral and papers etc) : http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%D2%B5%D3%E0%CA%FD%D1%A7%D1%D0%BE%BF&fr=itb_ofeed

Comment: @oen http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%D2%B5%D3%E0%CA%FD%D1%A7%D1%D0%BE%BF&fr=itb_ofeed   No 64 65 got relevant paper~

Comment: @Ryan: I suggest asking a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The result is
$$
-4\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)+4\zeta(3)\log^2(2)-\frac{2\pi^2}9 \log^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{20}\log2+\frac7{30}\log^5(2)+ \frac{63}8\zeta(5) =0.418709830998418751408037243448…
$$

Comment: Do you mean:$$-4\operatorname{Li}_5(\frac12)+4\zeta(3)\log^2(2)-\frac{2\pi^2}9 \log^3(2)-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{20}\log2+\frac7{30}\log^5(2)+ \frac{63}8\zeta(5)$$

Comment: Also: That seems to be correct, numerically. How did you get this?

Comment: A derivation of this closed form is given in [Cornel's book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-030-02462-8) as problem 1.8