# An Infinite Double Summation $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2k^2(n+k)^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

While Solving some integral problem, I encountered the following infinite series:

$$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2k^2(n+k)^2}$$

I have tried many methods including partial fractions... I seek help! Please provide hints if you don't have the complete answer.

Comment: Do you want to compute its value or only to prove that it converges?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We have $\begin{align} \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2k^2(n+k)^2} & = \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n+k)^3 - n^3-k^3}{n^3k^3(n+k)^3} \\ &= \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3k^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^3(n+k)^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^3(n+k)^3} \tag{*}\\ &=\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3k^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3k^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{n=k+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3k^3} \\&= \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n,k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3k^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{1 \le n < k <\infty} \frac{1}{n^3k^3} - \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{1 \le k < n < \infty} \frac{1}{n^3k^3} \\&= \frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n=k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3k^3} =  \frac{1}{3}\zeta(6) \end{align}$

where, in line $(*)$ we reindexed the summation with the change of variables $n+k \mapsto k$ in the second sum and $n+k \mapsto n$ in the third sum.

Comment: ABSOLUTELY AWESOME!!! (+1)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks ! :-)

Comment: Very clever. $\;$

Comment: Very creative approach! Have upvoted your answer.  Can you use the same technique in the case of $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^mk^m(n+k)^m}$$?

Comment: @hypergeometric ^_^ .. seems we can, denoting the series by $\displaystyle S_m = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{n^mk^m(n+k)^m}$, we can show $S_{2m+1} = -4\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}\binom{4m-2j+1}{2m}\zeta(2j)\zeta(6m-2j+3)$ and $S_{2m} = \frac{4}{3}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{m}\binom{4m-2j-1}{2m-1}\zeta(2j)\zeta(6m-2j)$ ..

Comment: @r9m -  That's amazing! Why don't you post this as a question and then post the answer? I'd like to see the full derivation, and I'm sure it will interest many others on here.

Comment: @hypergeometric This [paper](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa75/aa7522.pdf) contains an elementary derivation of a class of Euler Double summation !!

Comment: You really have sharingan power!!! :p

Comment: @Masacroso :P lol .. Thanks!

Comment: (+1) Where did you run across the paper on Tornheim’s double series?  Great find.  -Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV There's a wealth of information about papers [here](https://www.usna.edu/Users/math/meh/biblio.html) :-)

Comment: @r9m Thank you for the link.  Much appreciative.

Comment: interestingly we can show that this series also equals

$$
I=\int_{[0,1]^2}dxdy\frac{\text{Li}^2_2(xy)}{xy}
$$

which is terribly difficult to solve directly (and also mathematica didn't diggest it)

Comment: (+1)  I noticed that I failed to up vote this solid answer.  And Happy Holidays!

Comment: @Mark Thanks! Happy holidays to you too!

Comment: I didn't understand your notations in the last 2 lines. Can you please explain it?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari added some explanations in edit. Hope it clarifies the notations.

Comment: @ didn't understand the last step of changing the three sums into one. Also, why did you state $ n=k$?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari split the double sum $n,k \ge 1$ into $3$ cases $n>k$, $n < k$ or $n = k$.

Comment: @r9m one more question, what do they mean as the limits of the double sum?

Answer (score 15):

We have, $\displaystyle B_{2n}(x) = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{2(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(2\pi kx \right)}{k^{2n}}$

Cubing and integrating both sides,

\begin{align*}&\int_0^1 \left((-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2\pi)^{2n}}{2(2n)!}B_{2n}(x)\right)^3\,dx \\&= \int_0^1 \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos \left(2\pi kx \right)}{k^{2n}}\right)^3\,dx  \\&= \sum\limits_{k_1,k_2,k_3 = 1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{\cos \left(2\pi k_1x \right)\cos \left(2\pi k_2x \right)\cos \left(2\pi k_3x \right)}{k_1^{2n}k_2^{2n}k_3^{2n}}\,dx\\&= \frac{1}{4}\sum\limits_{k_1,k_2,k_3 = 1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\displaystyle \sum\limits_{\{\pm\}} \int_0^1 \cos \left(2\pi (k_1\pm k_2 \pm k_3)x \right)\,dx}{k_1^{2n}k_2^{2n}k_3^{2n}}\\&= \frac{3}{4}\sum\limits_{k_1,k_2= 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k_1^{2n}k_2^{2n}(k_1+k_2)^{2n}}\end{align*}

Since, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \cos \left(2\pi (k_1 + k_2 - k_3)x \right)\,dx = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ when } k_3 = k_1 + k_2\\ 0  &\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}$

The case $n = 1$,

$$\sum\limits_{k_1,k_2= 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k_1^{2}k_2^{2}(k_1+k_2)^{2}} = \frac{4\pi^6}{3}\int_0^1 \left(B_2(x)\right)^3\,dx = \frac{1}{3}\frac{\pi^6}{945} = \frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)$$

Comment: Nice use of the Fourier series of the Bernoulli polynomials.  (+1)