# Evaluate the double sum $\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{ 1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, special-functions

As a follow up of this [nice question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1292884/integral-involving-clausen-function-large-int-02-pi-operatornamecl-2x/1293101#1293101) I am interested in

$$
S_1=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}
$$

Furthermore, I would be also very grateful for a solution to

$$
S_2=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty}\frac{  1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}
$$

Following my answer in the question mentioned above and the numerical experiments of @Vladimir Reshetnikov it's very likely that at least

$$
S_1+S_2 = \frac{a}{b}\pi^6
$$

I think both sums may be evaluated by using partial fraction decomposition and the integral representation of the [Polygamma function](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygammafunktion) but I don't know how exactly and I guess there could be a much more efficient route.

Comment: The inner summation in the first line is summed from $n=0$ to $n-1$. This needs to be adjusted to make sense. As it should also be adjusted in the problem from whence this is first presented.

Comment: Sorry for the cross-edits, just making sure the title was covered too

Comment: no problem. now everthing should be fine... :)

Comment: Where does $m$ start?

Comment: argh...sorry. at $1$

Comment: shouldn't $m$ start at $2$ ? @tired

Comment: @RenatoFaraone Makes no difference (for $S_1$), since the inner sum is an empty sum for $m = 1$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clearly, $S_1$=$S_2$ (this can be shown by reversing the order of summation, as was noted above).
Using
$$
\frac{  1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}=\frac{  (m+n)^2-(m-n)^2}{4 m^2 n^2\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}
$$
we get
$$
S_1=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m n\left(m^2-n^2\right)^2}=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m-n\right)^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2},
$$
and after reversing the order of summation in the first sum
$$
S_1=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m-n\right)^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}=\\
\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}. \qquad\qquad (1)
$$

Let's introduce a third sum
$$
S_3=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}=\\
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{  1}{m^2 n^2\left(m+n\right)^2}-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(6).
$$
Using [An Infinite Double Summation $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2k^2(n+k)^2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1007926/an-infinite-double-summation) we get 
$$
S_3=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)-\frac{1}{8}\zeta(6)=\frac{1}{24}\zeta(6).\qquad\qquad\qquad (2)
$$
From (1) and (2) we get

$$
S_1=\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)-\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{24}\zeta(6)=\frac{7}{96}\zeta(6)=\frac{7}{96}\frac{\pi^6}{945}=\frac{\pi^6}{12960}
$$

Comment: excellent work (+1) , i was failing after your formula one back then....!

Answer (score 1):

Numerically, I get
$$
S_1+S_2 = 0.14836252987273216621
$$
which agrees with
$$
\frac{\pi^6}{6480}
$$
Also numerically,
$$
S_1 = 0.074181264936366083104
\\
S_2 = 0.074181264936366083104
$$
are seemingly equal.

Comment: very well! multiplying this by  $8\pi$ and adding  $\pi^7/70$gives us the result suggested by @Vladimir Reshetnikov

Comment: Do you have an idea where this symmerty come from? I'm not getting my head around it :/

Comment: Reverse the order of summation in $S_2$ and see what you get.

Comment: thanks, oh man today is not my brightest day!