# Is there other method to deal with $\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln^m (1+x y)}{(1+x y)^n}d x d y,$ where $m\ge 3?$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals, zeta-functions, reduction-formula

After finding the exact value of the  [integral](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-evaluate-the-double-integral-displaystyle-int_-0-1-int_-0-1-left-frac-ln-1-xy-1-xy-right-2-dx-dy/answer/Lai-Johnny?ch=17&oid=1477743739641358&share=6743e386&srid=CCOmo&target_type=answer), $$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln (1+x y)}{1+x y}\right)^2 d x d y=-\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}+\frac{1}{3} \ln ^3 2-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\ln ^2 2+2 \ln 2\,\tag*{} $$

I started to generalise it to
$$
I(m, n)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m (1+x y)}{(1+x y)^n} d x d y.
$$
Firstly I derived its reduction formula for integers $m,n \ge 1$ by integration by parts again.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n)&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m (1+x y)}{(1+x y)^n} d x d y \\
& =\int_0^1-\frac{1}{(n-1) y}\left[\int_0^1 \ln ^m(1+x y) d\left(\frac{1}{(1+x y)^{n-1}}\right)\right] d y \\
& =-\frac{1}{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{y}\left[\frac{\ln ^m(1+y)}{(1+y)^{n-1}}-m \int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^{m-1}(1+x y)}{(1+x y)} d x\right] dy \\
\end{aligned}
$$
So $$ \boxed{I(m, n) =-\frac{1}{n-1} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^m(1+y)}{y(1+y)^{n-1}} d y+\frac{m}{n-1} I(m-1, n)} \cdots(*)
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(2,2) 
& =-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y(1+y)} d y+2 I(1,2) \\
& =-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y(1+y)} d y+2\left[-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+y)}{y(1+y)}+2 I(0, 2)\right] \\
& =-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y(1+y)} d y-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+y)}{y(1+y)}+4 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+x y)^2} d y\\&= -\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y} d y+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{1+y} d y-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+y)}{y} d y-2 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1+y)}{1+y}dy+2\ln 2\\&= -\frac{\zeta(3)}{4}+\frac{\ln ^3 2}{3}-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\ln ^2 2+2 \ln 2 
\end{aligned}
$$
where the first integral uses the result :[How to evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1+x)}x\mathrm dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/316745/732917).

Similarly,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(2,3)=&-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y(1+y)^2} d y+I(1,3) \\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{y} d y-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{1+y}-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^2(1+y)}{(1+y)^2 }dy\right] +\frac{1}{24}\left(9-\pi^2+6 \ln ^2 2\right)\\=& -\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{3} \ln 2+\frac{7}{8}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now let’s go further.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(3,3) =&-\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{y(1+y)^2} d y+\frac{3}{2} I(2,3) \\
= & -\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{y} d y-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{1+y} d y-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{(1+y)^2}dy\right] +\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{3} \ln 2+\frac{7}{8}\right)\\=& -\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{y} d y-\frac{\ln ^4 2}{4}-3+\frac{\ln ^3 2}{2}(3+\ln 2)+3\ln 2\right]+ \frac{3}{2}\left( -\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{1}{3} \ln 2+\frac{7}{8}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Using the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3440584/732917), we have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln ^3(1+y)}{y} d y= -6 \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{21}{4} \zeta(3) \ln 2 +\frac{\pi^4}{15}-\frac{\ln ^4 2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}{4} \ln ^2 2
$$

Plugging back yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \quad  I(3,3)\\&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[ -6 \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{21}{4} \zeta(3) \ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{15}-\frac{\ln ^4 2}{4}+\frac{\pi^2}{4} \ln ^2 2 -\frac{\ln ^4 2}{4}-3+\frac{\ln ^3 2}{2}(3+\ln 2)+3 \ln 2\right] +\frac{3}{2}\left(-\frac{\zeta(3)}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{24}-\frac{\ln 2}{3}+\frac{7}{8}\right)\\&= 3 \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{45}{16} \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^4}{30}+\frac{\ln ^4 2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{8} \ln ^2 2+\frac{27}{32}-\ln ^3 2-\frac{3}{4} \ln 2+\frac{\pi^2}{32}
\end{aligned}
$$

Theoretically, we can use the [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3440584/732917), we have
and the reduction formula $(*)$ to evaluate tediously $$\int_0^1 \int_0^1\frac{\ln^m (1+x y)}{(1+x y)^n}d x d y,$$ where $m\ge 3$.

My **question** is whether there are other elegant methods.

Can you help me? Your comments and solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2161166/42969

Comment: **Conjecture:** For all integer $m \geq 1$, we have
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^m(1+y)}{y} d y = m! \zeta(m+1) + \frac{\ln^{m+1}2}{m+1} - \sum_{k=0}^m \frac{m!}{(m-k)!} \text{Li}_{k+1}(1/2) \ln^{m-k}2 $$
This probably can be proved by induction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluation of $\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+x)}{x} \ dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795867/evaluation-of-int-01-frac-log21xx-dx), in particular the answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3440584/1163258.

Comment: Gonçalo, thank you for your link  is very helpfull  to solve my double integral.

Comment: @Lai don’t change the question without clear explanation. It invalidates the answers that you got based on the previous version.

Comment: Sorry! For otherwise the question will be closed.