# Euler squared sum of order 2 : $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \mathcal{H}_n^{(2)} \right)^2}{n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, euler-sums

Let $\mathcal{H}_n$ denote the $n$ - th harmonic number. What techniques would one use to prove that

$$\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \mathcal{H}_n^{(2)} \right)^2}{n^2} = \zeta^2(3) + \frac{19 \zeta(6)}{24}$$

where $\zeta$ denotes the Riemann zeta function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since 
$$\left(\mathcal{H}_n^{(2)}\right)^2=\mathcal{H}_n^{(4)}+2\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\mathcal{H}_{k-1}^{(2)}}{k^2}$$
we can rewrite the sum in terms of [Multiple zeta functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function):
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \mathcal{H}_n^{(2)} \right)^2}{n^2}
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mathcal{H}_n^{(4)}}{n^2}+
2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\mathcal{H}_{k-1}^{(2)}}{k^2}\\
&=\left(\zeta(6)+\zeta(2,4)\right)+2(\zeta(2,2,2)+\zeta(4,2))\\
&=\zeta(6)+\left(\frac{25}{12}\zeta(6)-\zeta(3)^2\right)+2\left(\frac{\zeta(2)^3}{6}+\frac{\zeta(6)}{3}-\frac{\zeta(2)\zeta(4)}{2}\right)\\
&\qquad+2\left(\zeta(3)^2-\frac{4\zeta(6)}{3}\right)\\
&=\zeta(3)^2+\frac{19\pi^6}{22680}=\zeta(3)^2 + \frac{19 \zeta(6)}{24}
\end{align*}
where we also used the explicit values of 
$$\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6},\quad \zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}, \quad \zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945}.$$

Comment: Nice !!  Thank you!! :)

Answer (score 0):

We use the Abel's rearrangement over the $N$-th partial sum of the series,
\begin{align*}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2}{n^2} &= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N-1} \left[\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2-\left(H_{n+1}^{(2)}\right)^2\right]\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}+\left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^2\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \frac{1}{k^2}\\&= \left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^3 - \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} \frac{\left(H_n^{(2)}+H_{n+1}^{(2)}\right)H_n^{(2)}}{(n+1)^2}\\ &= \left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^3 - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{\left(2H_n^{(2)}-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)\left(H_n^{(2)}-\dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)}{n^2}\\&= \left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^3 - \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^2}\left(2\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2-3\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+\frac{1}{n^4}\right)\\ &= \frac{1}{3}\left(H_N^{(2)}\right)^3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}-\frac{1}{3}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^6}\end{align*}
I.e.,$$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2}{n^2} = \frac{1}{3}\zeta(2)^3+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}-\frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)$$
M.N.S.E showed in this answer one way of dealing with $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^4} = \zeta(3)^2 - \frac{1}{3}\zeta(6)$$ Combining the results lead to,
$$\Large\boxed{\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2}{n^2} = \color{blue}{\zeta(3)^2 + \frac{19}{24}\zeta(6)}}$$

Comment: Care to provide the link?

Comment: @Tolaso sorry i forgot to mention the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970106/prove-that-int-01-frac-rmli-2x-ln1-x-ln2xx-dx-frac-zeta/971605

Comment: Why downvote???,

Comment: I did not downvote...