# Challenging integral: Evaluate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers

How to evaluate $$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x}dx\ ?$$

I came across this integral $I$ while I was trying to compute two advanced sums of weight 7. The problem with my approach is that when I tried to evaluate $I_5$ 
 (shown below), the main integral $I$ appeared there which cancels out from both sides, so any idea how to evaluate $I_5$ or $I$?

Thanks.

**Here is my trial:**

Using the two generalized integral expressions of the polylogrithmic function which can be found in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums and series** page 4.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^n(u)}{1-xu}du=(-1)^n n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}
(x)\Longrightarrow \operatorname{Li}_{3}(x)=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2(u)}{1-xu}du\tag{1}$$

$$\small{u\int_0^1\frac{\ln^n(x)}{1-u+ux}dx=(-1)^{n-1}n!\operatorname{Li}_{n+1}\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)\Longrightarrow\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1-u+ux}dx=\frac6u\operatorname{Li}_{3}\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)}\tag{2}$$

We have

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x}dx\overset{\text{use} (1)}{=}\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x\ln^2u}{1-xu}du\right)dx\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-xu}dx\right)\ du\overset{1-x\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\frac12\int_0^1\ln^2u\left(\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1-u+ux}dx\right)\ du\\
&\overset{\text{use}\ (2)}{=}3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2u}{u}\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)du\overset{IBP}{=}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u(1-u)}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)du
\end{align}

Now we need the trilogarithmic identity:

$$\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)=\zeta(2)\ln x-\frac12\ln^2x\ln(1-x)+\frac16\ln^3x-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)-\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\zeta(3)$$

set $1-x=u$ to get

$$\small{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{u}{u-1}\right)=\zeta(2)\ln(1-u)-\frac12\ln^2(1-u)\ln u+\frac16\ln^3(1-u)-\operatorname{Li}_3(u)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)+\zeta(3)}$$

Going back to our integral
\begin{align}
I&=\small{-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u(1-u)}\left(\zeta(2)\ln(1-u)-\frac12\ln^2(1-u)\ln x+\frac16\ln^3(1-u)-\operatorname{Li}_3(u)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)+\zeta(3)\right)du}\\
&=-\zeta(2)\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du}_{\Large I_1}+\frac12\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\ln^2(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du}_{\Large I_2}-\frac16\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln^3(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du}_{\Large I_3}\\
&\quad+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\operatorname{Li}_3(u)}{u(1-u)}\ du}_{\Large I_4}+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u(1-u)}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)-\zeta(3)\right)du}_{\Large I_5}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
I_1=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1 u^{n-1}\ln^3udu=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}
\end{align}
.

---

\begin{align}
I_2&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\ln^2(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\int_0^1 u^{n-1}\ln^4udu\\
&=24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}=24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^5}-24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
I_3&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln^3(1-u)}{u(1-u)}du=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln^3(1-u)}{u}du+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln^3(1-u)}{1-u}du}_{1-x\ \mapsto\ x}\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\ln^3(1-u)}{u}\ du\overset{IBP}{=}\frac32\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\ln^2(1-u)}{1-u}du\\
&=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)\int_0^1 u^n\ln^4udu, \quad \text{reindex}\\
&=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac2{n^2}\right)\int_0^1 u^{n-1}\ln^4u du\\
&=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac2{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{24}{n^5}\right)\\
&=36\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^5}-36\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}-72\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}+72\zeta(7)
\end{align}
.

---

\begin{align}
I_4&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u\operatorname{Li}_3(u)}{u(1-u)}du=\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(3)}\int_0^1 u^{n-1}\ln^3u du=-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^4}
\end{align}

---

\begin{align}
I_5&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u(1-u)}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)-\zeta(3)\right)du\\
&=\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{u}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)-\zeta(3)\right)du}_{IBP}+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}\left(\operatorname{Li}_3(1-u)-\zeta(3)\right)\ du}_{1-u\ \mapsto\ u}\\
&=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\operatorname{Li}_2(1-u)}{1-u}du+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-u)\operatorname{Li}_3(u)}{u}du}_{\large \text{our main integral}}-\zeta(3)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3u}{1-u}du\\
&=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\operatorname{Li}_2(1-u)}{1-u}du+I+6\zeta(3)\zeta(4)
\end{align}

In my solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314639) I came across the remaining integral and here is the result:

$$\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4u\operatorname{Li}_2(1-u)}{1-u}du=6\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+36\zeta(7)-30\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}$$

Then

$$I_5=I+6\zeta(3)\zeta(4)+6\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+36\zeta(7)-30\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}$$
.

---

**Note:** We can not use the two sums $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}} {n^4}$ in our solution because the integral $I$ is the key to evaluate these two sums.

Comment: I assume $\mbox{Li}_3$ denotes a 3-atom Lithium molecule?

Comment: @Michael  here is the definition $\operatorname{Li}_a(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n^a}$. its called polylogarithmic function.

Comment: So you want a solution in terms of Euler sums?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt it's fine if you write solution in terms of easy sums not the sums I mentioned in the note.

Answer (score 20):

We can write
$$
\ln(1-x)=-\int_0^x \frac{dt}{1-t},\hspace{7mm}\operatorname{Li}_3(x)=\int_{0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq t_3\leq x}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3}.
$$
We can multiply out $\ln(1-x)^3\operatorname{Li}_3(x)$ and break the result into a sum over the different possible orderings of the variables of integration. This will allow us to write $I$ as an integer linear combination of terms of the form
$$
\int_{0\leq t_1\leq t_2\leq t_3\leq t_4\leq t_5\leq t_6\leq t_7\leq 1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{f_1(t_1)f_2(t_2)f_3(t_3)f_4(t_4)f_5(t_5)f_6(t_6)f_7(t_7)},
$$
where three of the functions $f_i$ are $f_i(x)=x$ and the other four are $f_i(x)=1-x$. Each of these latter integrals is a [multiple zeta value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_zeta_function) of depth $4$ and weight $7$. It's a bit messy, but I find
$$
I = -24\zeta(4, 1, 1, 1)-18\zeta(3, 2, 1, 1)-18\zeta(2, 3, 1, 1)-12\zeta(3, 1, 2, 1)-12\zeta(2, 2, 2, 1)-12\zeta(2, 1, 3, 1)-6\zeta(3, 1, 1, 2)-6\zeta(2, 2, 1, 2)-6\zeta(2, 1, 2, 2)-6\zeta(2, 1, 1, 3).
$$
Every multiple zeta value of weight $7$ can be written in terms of the Riemann zeta function. There are a number of different ways to work out these expressions. One way is to use the generalized double-shuffle relations (see the paper [1]), and the expressions have been tabulated [here](https://www.nikhef.nl/~form/datamine/datamine.html). The result is
$$
I=-\frac{327}{8}\zeta(7)+\frac{21}{5}\zeta(2)^{2}\zeta(3)+12\zeta(2)\zeta(5).
$$

[1] *Ihara, Kentaro; Kaneko, Masanobu; Zagier, Don*, [**Derivation and double shuffle relations for multiple zeta values**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X0500182X), Compos. Math. 142, No. 2, 307-338 (2006). [ZBL1186.11053](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1186.11053).

Comment: thanks for the efforts. Using MZV seems very helpful for high weight series. To be honest i didn't understand the solution as i am not familiar with it so i need to study this topic well. I prefer common methods though as they are more understandable for me and people.

Comment: @JulianRosen: Nice answer, interesting references (+1).

Answer (score 14):

This post is a supplement to the nice answer from @JulianRosen.  We go into some details thereby confirming  his  results, the  intermediate result as well  as the final one. As  this post          is rather lengthy albeit simple, here is short  overview:

- **Step 1:** Representation of $I$  by  multiple zeta values (MZV) confirming Julian Rosen's intermediate result.
- **Step 2:** Simplification of $I$ by application of a sum relation  and the duality theorem for MZVs.
- **Step 3:** We make a shortcut and use *[EZ-Face](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/EZFace/zetaform.cgi)*, an MZV calculator, to find linear dependencies of MZVs. This way we obtain and thereby confirm Julian Rosen's final result.

> **Step1:** Representation of $I$  by  multiple zeta values (MZV)
>
> We start with
>   \begin{align*}
> I&=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\ln^3(1-x)\mathrm{Li}_3(x)\,dx\\
> &=\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\left(-\int_0^x\frac{dt}{1-t}\right)^3\int_{0<t_1<t_2<t_3<x}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3}\,dx\\
> &=-\int_{{0<t_1<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}\atop{0<t_4,t_5,t_6<t_7<1}}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}

In (1) we rewrite the integral to easily see how the region of integration
\begin{align*}
\{(t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6,t_7): 0<t_1<t_2<t_3<t_7<1,0<t_4,t_5,t_6<t_7<1\}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
 is to split in order to obtain an integral representations of the MZVs of the form
\begin{align*}
\int_{0<t_1<t_2<t_3<t_4<t_5<t_6<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}
\end{align*}
See e.g. chapter 7 of *[Lectures on Multiple Zeta Values](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~michel.waldschmidt/articles/pdf/MZV2011IMSc.pdf)* by W. Zudilin for more information.

> Each of the following integrals has a factor $6$ since according to the region of integration in (2) we can permute $t_4,t_5,t_6$.
>
> We obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> I&=(-6)\left(\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\qquad\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &=(-6)\left(4\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_2<t_3<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_2t_3t_7}\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad+3\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_2\,dt_6\,dt_3\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)(1-t_5)t_2(t-t_6)t_3t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+3\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)(1-t_5)t_2t_3(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+2\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_2\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_3\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)t_2(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_3t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+2\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_2\,dt_5\,dt_3\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)t_2(1-t_5)t_3(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+2\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_4\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)(1-t_4)t_2t_3(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_3<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_3\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t-2(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_3t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_3\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2(1-t_4)(1-t_5)t_3(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<\color{blue}{t_4}<t_3<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_4\,dt_3\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2(1-t_4)t_3(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\int_{0<\color{blue}{t_1}<t_2<t_3<\color{blue}{t_4}<\color{blue}{t_5}<\color{blue}{t_6}<t_7<1}\frac{dt_1\,dt_2\,dt_3\,dt_4\,dt_5\,dt_6\,dt_7}{(1-t_1)t_2t_3(1-t_4)(1-t_5)(t-t_6)t_7}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &=(-6)\left(4\zeta(4,1,1,1)+3\zeta(3,2,1,1)+3\zeta(2,3,1,1)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad+2\zeta(3,1,2,1)+2\zeta(2,2,2,1)+2\zeta(2,1,3,1)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.+\zeta(3,1,1,2)+\zeta(2,2,1,2)+\zeta(2,1,2,2)+\zeta(2,1,1,3)\right)\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
>   in accordance with the intermediate result of Julian Rosen.

In (3) we marked the indices $t_1,t_4,t_5,t_6$ corresponding to $\frac{1}{1-t_j}$ blue, to better see the structure of the integral. In (4) we collect all terms with the same structure (appropriately substituing indices thereby).

> **Step 2:** Simplification of $I$
>
> Here we recall the *Sum theorem* (Theorem 2.5 in W. Zudilins paper): For any integer $s>1$ and $l\geq 1$ the following holds,
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{{s_1>1,s_2\geq 1,\ldots,s_l\geq 1}\atop{s_1+s_2+\cdots+s_l=s}}\zeta(s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_l)=\zeta(s)
> \end{align*}

Setting $l=4$ and $s=7$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\zeta(7)&=\zeta(4,1,1,1)+\zeta(3,2,1,1)+\zeta(2,3,1,1)\\
&+\zeta(3,1,2,1)+\zeta(2,2,2,1)+\zeta(2,1,3,1)\\
&+\zeta(3,1,1,2)+\zeta(2,2,1,2)+\zeta(2,1,2,2)\\
&+\zeta(2,1,1,3)
\end{align*}

> Putting this relation into (5) we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{I}&\color{blue}{=(-6)\left(3\zeta(4,1,1,1)+2\zeta(3,2,1,1)+2\zeta(2,3,1,1)\right.}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\color{blue}{+\zeta(3,1,2,1)+\zeta(2,2,2,1)+\zeta(2,1,3,1)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad\color{blue}{\left.+\zeta(7)\right)}\tag{6}
> \end{align*}

Next we apply the duality theorem (Theorem 3.7 in W. Zudilins paper) and replace this way the MZVs with length $4$ with MZVs of length $3$.

We obtain from (6)
\begin{align*}
\zeta(4,1,1,1)&=Z(x^3y\cdot y\cdot y\cdot y)=Z(x^3y^4)=Z(x^4y^3)=\zeta(5,1,1)\\
\zeta(3,2,1,1)&=Z(x^2y\cdot xy\cdot y\cdot y)=Z(x^2yxy^3)=Z(x^3yxy^2)=\zeta(4,2,1)\\
\zeta(2,3,1,1)&=Z(xy\cdot x^2y\cdot y\cdot y)=Z(xyx^2y^3)=Z(x^3y^2xy)=\zeta(4,1,2)\\
\zeta(3,1,2,1)&=Z(x^2y\cdot  y\cdot xy\cdot y)=Z(x^2y^2xy^2)=Z(x^2yx^2y^2)=\zeta(3,3,1)\\
\zeta(2,2,2,1)&=Z(xy\cdot      xy\cdot        xy\cdot     y)=Z(xyxyxy^2)=Z(x^2yxyxy)=\zeta(3,2,2)\\
\zeta(2,1,3,1)&=Z(xy\cdot y\cdot x^2y\cdot y)=Z(xy^2x^2y^2)=Z(x^2y^2x^2y)=\zeta(3,1,3)\tag{7}
\end{align*}

> From (6) and (7) we derive a simpler representation
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{I}&\color{blue}{=(-6)\left(3\zeta(5,1,1)+2\zeta(4,2,1)+2\zeta(4,1,2)\right.}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\zeta(3,3,1)+\zeta(3,2,2)+\zeta(3,1,3)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{\left.+\zeta(7)\right)}\tag{8}
> \end{align*}

**Step 3:** Representation of  $I$ with single zeta values

We know that MZVs of weight $7$ are in the $\mathbb{Q}$-linear span of $\zeta(7),\zeta(2)^2\zeta(3)$ and $\zeta(2)\zeta(5)$. See e.g. exercise 3.3 (iv) in W. Zudilins paper. We use *[EZ-Face](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/EZFace/zetaform.cgi)* to find the linear relations.

E.g. typing the input

\begin{align*}
               \mathrm{lindep}([z(7),z(2)*z(2)*z(3), z(2)*z(5), z(5,1,1)])
\end{align*}

The output is:

\begin{align*}
               [10, -1., -4.,-2.]
\end{align*}

which means
\begin{align*}
10\zeta(7)-\zeta(2)^2\zeta(3)-4\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-2\zeta(5,1,1,1)=0
\end{align*}

We find this way the coefficients of the  linear expressions for all MZVs of length  $4$ in (8) as

$$
\begin{array}{rrr|r|c}
\zeta(7)&\zeta(2)^2\zeta(3)&\zeta(2)\zeta(5)&\zeta(\mathrm{arg})&\mathrm{arg}\\
\hline
10&-1&-4&-2&(5,1,1)\\
1105&-112&-440&80&(4,2,1)\\
-5&12&-20&8&(4,1,2)\\
-61&0&36&8&(3,3,1)\\
-785&-72&600&80&(3,2,2)\\
-5&2&0&-20&(3,1,3)
\end{array}
$$

> Substituting the  MZVs in (8) with the linear representation of the table we finally obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{I}&\color{blue}{=(-6)\left(3\zeta(5,1,1)+2\zeta(4,2,1)+2\zeta(4,1,2)\right.}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{+\zeta(3,3,1)+\zeta(3,2,2)+\zeta(3,1,3)}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{\left.+\zeta(7)\right)}\\
> &=(-6)\left(\zeta(7)\left(3\cdot\frac{10}{2}-2\cdot\frac{1105}{80}+2\cdot\frac{5}{8}+\frac{61}{8}+\frac{785}{80}-\frac{5}{20}+1\right)\right.\\
> &\qquad\qquad\quad+\zeta(2)^2\zeta(3)\left(-3\cdot\frac{1}{2}+2\cdot\frac{112}{80}-2\cdot\frac{12}{8}+0+\frac{72}{80}+\frac{2}{20}\right)\\
> &\qquad\qquad\left.\quad+\zeta(2)\zeta(5)\left(-3\cdot\frac{4}{2}+2\cdot\frac{440}{80}+2\cdot\frac{20}{8}-\frac{36}{8}-\frac{600}{80}+0\right)\right)\\
> &\color{blue}{=-\frac{327}{8}\zeta(7)+\frac{21}{5}\zeta(2)^2\zeta(3)+12\zeta(2)\zeta(5)}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> in accordance  with Julian Rosen's   result.

Comment: Fantastic answer.

Comment: @Klangen: Many thanks for your nice comment and the credit.