# How to evaluate: $\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\cdot \ln^2(x) \, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\cdot \ln^2(x)\,\mathrm dx=1.03693\ldots$$

This number looks like $\zeta(5)$ value.

We expand the terms

$$\int_0^1\frac{\frac{\pi^2}{6}}{1-x}\cdot \ln^2(x) \, \mathrm dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x} \cdot \ln^2(x) \, \mathrm dx$$

$$2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\cdot \ln^2(x) \, \mathrm dx$$

this last integral it is very complicate to compute...

Can any user please help to show that whether this value is equal to $\zeta(5)$ or not?

Comment: A clarification: but $\mathrm{li(x)}$ is the logarithmic integral. What is $\mathrm{Li}_2$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html

Comment: Set $1-x=y$  then use $\ln^2(1-y)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_{n-1}}{n}y^n$.

Comment: You can find hundreds of similar questions here. May I ask what is the motivation of this particular problem?

Comment: Dr. Wolfgang hintze where is the link. Thank you

Comment: For instance this one (see under "related") https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3458107/198592 is similar and even more complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can have a nice generalization for

$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{\zeta(n)-\operatorname{Li}_n(1-x)}{1-x}\ln^2x\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\zeta(n)-\operatorname{Li}_n(x)}{x}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx$$

---

From $$\ln^2(1-x)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}x^k$$

It follows that

$$I_n=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\int_0^1x^{k-1}(\zeta(n)-\operatorname{Li}_n(x))\ dx$$
By integration by parts we have

$$\int_0^1x^{k-1}\operatorname{Li}_n(x)\ dx=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_k}{k^n}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{\zeta(n-i+1)}{k^i}$$

$$\Longrightarrow I_n=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{\zeta(n)}{k}+(-1)^{n}\frac{H_k}{k^n}+\sum_{i=\color{red}{1}}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{\zeta(n-i+1)}{k^i}\right)$$

or

$$I_n=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\sum_{i=\color{red}{2}}^{n-1}(-1)^i\frac{\zeta(n-i+1)}{k^i}+(-1)^{n}\frac{H_k}{k^n}\right),\quad n=2,3,...$$

---

**Applications**

$$I_2=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{H_k}{k^2}\right)$$

$$ I_3=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{k^2}-\frac{H_k}{k^3}\right)$$

$$I_4=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{\zeta(3)}{k^2}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{k^3}+\frac{H_k}{k^4}\right)$$

$$I_5=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}\left(\frac{\zeta(4)}{k^2}-\frac{\zeta(3)}{k^3}+\frac{\zeta(2)}{k^4}-\frac{H_k}{k^5}\right)$$

Comment: excellent, (+1)

Comment: @Dr. Li Pin Poo thank you, glad you like it :)

Answer (score 5):

Start with $1-x\mapsto x$
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\ln^2x}{1-x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$

By Cauchy product we have

$$\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac3{n^3}\right)x^n$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and use the fact that $-\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n}{n}$ we get

$$I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac3{n^3}\right)\left(\frac{H_n}{n}\right)$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}$$

For the first sum, its evaluated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3204618)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}=\frac72\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

The second sum, can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3236618)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

and the well-known result

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Combine the three sums to get

$$\boxed{I=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\zeta(5)}$$

---

A different approach is to apply integration by parts to your original integral before breaking the inegrand.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier way, let $1-x\mapsto x$

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}\ln^2x\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx$$

Now use $\ln^2(1-x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}x^n$ we get

$$I=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}(\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x))\ dx$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}+\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)$$

$$=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}$$

These two sums are mentioned in my previous solution above, collecting them gives $ I=\zeta(5)$

Answer (score 2):

A solution that is not using harmonic series.

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\Big(\operatorname{Li}_2(1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\Big)\ln^2(x)}{1-x} \, \mathrm dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\right)\Big(\operatorname{Li}_2(1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)\Big)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\right)\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&=2\zeta(3)\zeta(2)+\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt\right)\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-\int_0^1 \left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt\right)\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}dx\\
&=-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln(tx)\ln^2 x}{(1-tx)(1-x)}\,dtdx\\
&=\int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln(tx)\ln^2 x}{(1-t)(1-tx)}-\frac{\ln(tx)\ln^2 x}{(1-t)(1-x)}\right)dt dx\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^3(tx)-2\ln t\ln^2(tx)+\ln^2 t\ln(tx)}{(1-t)(1-tx)}-\frac{\ln^3 x}{(1-t)(1-x)}\right)dt dx\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_t^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)dt+\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)dt\\&-\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln t}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}du\right)dt -2\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}du\right)dt}_{J-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}+\\&\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dt+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dt}_{-J}\\
&=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_t^1 \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)dt+\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du\right)dt\\&-\int_0^1 \frac{2\ln t}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}du\right)dt -2\Big(J-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\Big)+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 t}{t}\left(\int_0^t \frac{\ln u}{1-u}du\right)dt-J\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-3J+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt-\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}dt\\
&=6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-3J+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt-8\zeta(5)
\end{align}
On the other hand,
\begin{align}K&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-t)\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt,C=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=\left[\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-C\right)\ln(1-t)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-t}\left(\int_0^t\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}du-C\right)dt\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{t\ln^3 (tu)}{(1-tu)(1-t)}-\frac{C}{1-t}\right)dt du\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\left(\frac{\ln^3 (tu)}{(1-t)(1-u)}-\frac{\ln^3 (tu)}{(1-u)(1-tu)}-\frac{C}{1-t}\right)dt du\\
&=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-u}\left(\int_u^1\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt\right)du-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{u}\left(\int_0^u\frac{\ln^3 t}{1-t}dt\right)du+\\&\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\ln^3 u}{(1-t)(1-u)}-\frac{C}{1-t}\right)dt du\\
&\overset{\text{IBP}}=-12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-J+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4 u}{1-u}du+\underbrace{\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(\frac{\ln^3 u}{(1-t)(1-u)}-\frac{C}{1-t}\right)dt du}_{L}\\
&0\leq A<1\\
L(A)&=\int_0^A \int_0^A \left(\frac{\ln^3 u}{(1-t)(1-u)}-\frac{C}{1-t}\right)dt du\\
&=\ln(1-A)\int_0^A \left(C-\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u}\right)du\\
&=\ln(1-A)\int_A^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx-(1-A)\ln(1-A)C\\
L&=\lim_{A\rightarrow 1}L(A)\\&=0\\
K&=\boxed{-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+12\zeta(5)}\\
\end{align}
Therefore,

$\boxed{\displaystyle J=\zeta(5)}$

I assume that,
\begin{align}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln t}{1-t}dt&=-\zeta(2)=-\frac{1}{6}\pi^2\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}dt&=2\zeta(3)\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^4 t}{1-t}dt&=24\zeta(5)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach through the harmonic sum thicket.

Starting with *Euler's reflexion formula for the dilogarithm function*, [namely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Identities)
$$\operatorname{Li}_2 (x) + \operatorname{Li}_2 (1 - x) = \zeta (2) - \ln x \ln (1- x),$$
your integral $I$ can be rewritten as
$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x \ln (1 - x)}{1 - x} \, dx + \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \operatorname{Li}_2 (x)}{1 - x} \, dx = I_1 + I_2.$$

For the first integral, from the *generating function* for the *harmonic numbers* $H_n$ we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generating_functions)
$$\frac{\ln (1 - x)}{1 - x} = - \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H_n x^n.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
I_1 &= -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty H_n \int_0^1 x^n \ln^3 x \, dx\\
&= -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty H_n \frac{d^3}{ds^3} \left [\int_0^1 x^{n + s} \, dx \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= -\sum_{n = 1}^\infty H_n \frac{d^3}{ds^3} \left [\frac{1}{n + s + 1} \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{(n + 1)^4} = 6 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H_{n - 1}}{n^4},
\end{align}
after reindexing $n \mapsto n - 1$. Since
$$H_n = H_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n},$$
this leads to
$$I_1 = 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} - 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} - 6 \zeta (5).$$

For the second integral, from the *generating function* for the *generalised harmonic numbers* of order two $H^{(2)}_n$ we [have](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Generalizations)
$$\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2 (x)}{1 - x} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H^{(2)}_n x^n.$$
Thus
\begin{align}
I_2 &= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H^{(2)}_n \int_0^1 x^n \ln^2 x \, dx\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H^{(2)}_n \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left [\int_0^1 x^{n + s} \, dx \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= \sum_{n = 1}^\infty H^{(2)}_n \frac{d^2}{ds^2} \left [\frac{1}{n + s + 1} \right ]_{s = 0}\\
&= 2\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{(n + 1)^3} = 2 \sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_{n-1}}{n^3},
\end{align}
after reindexing $n \mapsto n - 1$. Since
$$H^{(2)}_n = H^{(2)}_{n - 1} + \frac{1}{n^2},$$
we have
$$I_2 = 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^3} - 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^5} = 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^3} - 2 \zeta (5).$$

Returning to our integral, we have
$$I = 6 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^3} - 8 \zeta (5).$$
Since
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^4} = 3 \zeta (5) - \zeta (2) \zeta (3),$$
and
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H^{(2)}_n}{n^3} = 3 \zeta (2) \zeta (3) - \frac{9}{2} \zeta (5),$$
it is immedate that $I = \zeta (5)$, as desired.

Comment: @Ali Shather Indeed. Fixed and thanks.