# A group of advanced harmonic series with weight of 9

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I managed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3406737/advanced-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n4-6h-n2h-n28h-nh-n33) to prove that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^4-6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2-6H_n^{(4)}}{n^5}\\=672\zeta(9)-240\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-105\zeta(3)\zeta(6)-168\zeta(4)\zeta(5)+24\zeta^3(3)$$

Where $H_n^{(r)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^r}$ is the harmonic number and $\zeta$ is The Riemann zeta function.

Also I managed to find the last sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^{(4)}}{n^5}=5\zeta(4)\zeta(5)+35\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-\frac{125}2\zeta(9).$$ My question here, is it possible to find the other four sums? and if so, are they known in the literature?