# Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

How to prove, without calculating each sum separately that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}=24\zeta(7)-4\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-15\zeta(3)\zeta(4)\ ?$$
>   where $H_n^{(r)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^r}$ is the generalized harmonic number and $\zeta$ is Riemann zeta function.

---

This problem is already proved by **Cornel**  in his book ***Almost Impossible Integrals, Sums and Series*** page 299 where he used only pure series manipulations.

The question here is can we prove it in a different way?

---

If you are curious about the result of each sum,  you can find them in the same book page 301-302.

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}=\frac{231}{16}\zeta(7)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac{51}{4}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}=-\frac{51}{16}\zeta(7)+2\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)\zeta(4)$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is my proof using integration and results of some manageable Euler sums:

From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number) we have

$$\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}\right)x^n\overset{\text{reindex}}{=}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac2{n^2}\right)x^{n-1}\tag1$$

$$-\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)x^n\tag2$$

If we multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $-\frac{\ln^3x}{6x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1$

and use the fact that $-\frac16\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3x\ dx=\frac1{n^4}$ ,we obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{n^4}=\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^3(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\frac16\mathcal I$$

Where

\begin{align}
\mathcal I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^3(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx}_{1-x\ \mapsto\ x}\\
&=2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\ dx\overset{IBP}{=}\frac32\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx\\
&\overset{(1)}{=}\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac2{n^2}\right)\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^4x\ dx\\
&=\frac32\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(H_n^2-H_n^{(2)}-\frac{2H_n}{n}+\frac2{n^2}\right)\left(\frac{24}{n^5}\right)\\
&=36\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^5}-36\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}-72\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}+72\zeta(7)
\end{align}

Substitute the value of $\mathcal I$ and rearrange the terms we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^5}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^4}-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}+12\zeta(7)$$

We have :

$$\mathcal S_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^5}=6\zeta(7)-\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\frac52\zeta(3)\zeta(4)$$

$$\mathcal S_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}=-10\zeta(7)+5\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+2\zeta(3)\zeta(4)$$

$$\mathcal S_3=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^4}=18\zeta(7)-10\zeta(2)\zeta(5)$$

$$\mathcal S_4=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}=4\zeta(7)-\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\zeta(3)\zeta(4)$$

By collecting these results, we get the closed form of the problem.

---

Note: $\mathcal S_1$ is calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314894), $\mathcal S_2$ and $\mathcal S_3$ are calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314639) and $\mathcal S_4$ is easy to get by using Euler identity.