# Looking for closed form for $\int_0^1\frac{\log^2x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\log^2\left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1+x\right)}\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

I was evaluating and integral involving iterated logarithms when the following integral appeared:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log^2x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\log^2\left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1+x\right)}\ \mathrm{d}x$$
which I have no idea how to tackle. I am sure it can be represented as an Euler sum, but do not know how to arrive at such a result. Wolfram gives the equality of 
$$\int_0^1\frac{\log^2x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\log^2\left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1+x\right)}\ \mathrm{d}x =0.305108.$$
Any hints would be greatly appreciated; thanks!

Related problem: 
[Compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^4}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^4}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399744/compute-sum-n-1-infty-frach-n3n4-3-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nh-n2)

Comment: Nice problem (+1). I suggest following the same technique here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531956

Comment: In the question title, you have the bounds as $0$ to $\infty$, but then in the body, you have the bounds as $0$ to $1$. Which did you mean?

Comment: I think he meant 0 to 1 which is around 0.305.

Comment: Yes, I will fix that -- thank you! I have found a potential technique that I am going to explore. It connects a related integral to this and uses it's solution. I will post more about it if I find anything sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\ln^2\left(1+x\right)}{x\left(1+x\right)}dx$$

$$\small{=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^3(1+x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^3(1+x)}{1+x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^2(1+x)}{1+x}dx}$$

$$=I_1-I_2-I_3+I_4$$

By integration by parts

$$I_2=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln^4(1+x)}{x}dx$$

$$I_4=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^3(1+x)}{x}dx=-I_1$$

Thus, the integral boils down to

$$I=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln^4(1+x)}{x}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx$$

$$=\frac12A-B$$

The first integral is calculated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3249294)

$$A\small{=-120\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac12\right)-72\ln2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-24\ln^22\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+78\zeta(6)+\frac34\ln2\zeta(5)-\frac32\ln^22\zeta(4)}$$
$$\small{-3\ln^32\zeta(3)+2\ln^42\zeta(2)+12\zeta^2(3)-12\ln2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{17}{30}\ln^62+24\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^52^n}}$$

For the second integral, use $\ln^2(1+x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{n-1}x^n$

$$B=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n}H_{n-1}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3xdx=-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^5}H_{n-1}$$

$$=-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}+12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^6}=-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}-\frac{93}{8}\zeta(6)$$

Collecting the two integrals we have

$$I=\small{-60\operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac12\right)-36\ln2\operatorname{Li}_5\left(\frac12\right)-12\ln^22\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{405}{8}\zeta(6)+\frac38\ln2\zeta(5)-\frac34\ln^22\zeta(4)}$$
$$\small{-\frac32\ln^32\zeta(3)+\ln^42\zeta(2)+6\zeta^2(3)-6\ln2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{17}{60}\ln^62+12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^52^n}+12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}}$$

Unfortunately, there is no closed form for your integral as the latter two sums have no known closed forms.

Comment: These exists a relation between the last two sums, so the result can be simplified a bit more. : )

Comment: @Edit profile and settings I agree but just more tedious calculations.