# Evaluating $\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)\log(1-x) \log(x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, harmonic-numbers

In this [thread](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic119.html)

a friend posted the following integral

$$I=\int^1_0 \frac{\log(1+x)\log(1-x) \log(x)}{x}\, \mathrm dx$$

The best we could do is expressing it in terms of Euler sums

$$I=-\frac{\zeta^2(2)}{2}+ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2} H_{n}^{(2)}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^3}H_{n}$$

I am wondering if the approach I followed made the integral complicated ?
What approach would you follow to solve the integral?, can we find a better solution ?

Comment: By the way, why are you interested in Euler sums?

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal, I was working with polylogarithm function and I found an intimate relation with Euler sums .

Comment: @mhenniBenghorbal, sorry I don't get what you are saying ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The values of the two Euler Sums are

$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n^{3}} = \frac{11\pi^4}{360}-2\text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)-\frac{7}{4}\log(2) \zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\log^2(2)-\frac{1}{12}\log^4(2)$$
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^{2}}  =-\frac{17}{480}\pi^4 +4 \text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)+\frac{7}{2}\log(2) \zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2 \log^2(2)}{6}+\frac{\log^4(2)}{6}$$

Therefore the integral evaluates to

> $$\begin{align*} \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log(x)\log(1+x)}{x}dx &=-\frac{3 \pi^4}{160}+\frac{7\log(2)}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\pi^2 \log^2(2)}{12} +\frac{\log^4(2)}{12} \\ &\quad+ 2 \text{Li}_4 \left(\frac{1}{2} \right) \sim 0.290721 \end{align*}$$

Refer to [this page](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic136-20.html) for the evaluation of Euler Sums.

Comment: The following [relation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458852/interesting-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1k-1k2h-k2/469527#469527) is useful for your calculations.

Answer (score 6):

using an identity devoloped by Cornel Ioan Valean and it can be found in his book " **Almost impossible integrals, sums, and series**":
$$\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)x^{2n} $$
we get:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\ln x}{x}\ dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)\int_0^1x^{2n-1}\ln x\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_{2n}-H_n}{n}+\frac1{2n^2}\right)\left(-\frac1{(2n)^2}\right)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^3}-\frac14\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}+\frac18\zeta(4)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^3}+\frac34\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}+\frac18\zeta(4)\\
&=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac1{12}\ln^42
\end{align}

where we used the value of the first sum proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k/3219475#3219475) and the common value of the second sum which is $\frac54\zeta(4)$.

Answer (score 5):

**A solution by Cornel Ioan Valean** (the nice, interesting part about this solution is that we calculate the integral **without using harmonic series, Beta function** at all)

> **Proof.** Multiplying both sides of $i)$ (see below) by $1/(1-a)$ and integrating from $a=0$ to $a=1/2$, we obtain
>   $$\int_0^{1/2}\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log (1-x)}{(1-a x)(1-a)} \textrm{d}x\right)\textrm{d}a=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\log (x) \log (1-x)}{(1-a x)(1-a)} \textrm{d}a\right)\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log (1-x) \log (2-x)}{1-x} \textrm{d}x=\int_0^1 \frac{\log (1-x) \log (x) \log (1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{ \log (1-a)}{a(1-a)}\textrm{d}a+\frac{1}{6}\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log ^3(1-a)}{a(1-a)}\textrm{d}a+\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(a)}{a(1-a)}\textrm{d}a$$
>   $$-\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{a(1-a)}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right) \textrm{d}a$$
>   $$=\frac{1}{12}\log^4(2)-\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{7}{4}\log(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(4)+2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right),$$
>   and the solution is complete.

In the calculations we needed the following results:

Let $a<1$ be a real number. The following equality holds:
$$i) \ \int_0^1 \frac{\log (x) \log (1-x)}{1-a x} \textrm{d}x=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\frac{ \log (1-a)}{a}+\frac{1}{6}\frac{\log ^3(1-a)}{a}+\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{Li}_3(a)-\frac{1}{a}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right),$$
 where $\operatorname{Li}_3$ is the Trilogarithm function. The result is stated and proved in the paper  [A special way of extracting the real part of the Trilogarithm,  $ \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1\pm i}{2}\right)$ by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337868999).

$$ii) \ \int_0^a \frac{\log (1-x)}{x (1-x)}\textrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(1-a)-\operatorname{Li}_2(a).$$

$$iii) \ \int_0^a \frac{\log ^3(1-x)}{x (1-x)} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=6 \operatorname{Li}_4(1-a)-6 \operatorname{Li}_3(1-a) \log (1-a)+3 \operatorname{Li}_2(1-a) \log ^2(1-a)$$
$$-\frac{1}{4} \log ^4(1-a)+\log (a) \log ^3(1-a)-\frac{\pi^4}{15},$$

which is straightforward with integration by parts.

$$iv) \ \int_0^a \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{1-x} \textrm{d}x=-\frac{1}{2}(\operatorname{Li}_2(a))^2-\operatorname{Li}_3(a) \log (1-a),$$

and it's straightforward with integration by parts.

$$v) \ \int_0^a \frac{1}{x(1-x)}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\textrm{d}x =\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{a}{a-1}\right).$$

$$vi) \ \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}(\zeta(2)-\log^2(2)).$$

$$ vii) \ \operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{6}\log^3(2).$$

**A first note:** A generalization of the present integral with $\log^{2n}(x)$ is given in the book **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (see page 6),

> $$\int_0^1\frac{\log(1-x)\log^{2n}(x)\log(1+x)}{x} \textrm{d}x =\frac{1}{2}(2n)!\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right)\sum_{k=1}^{2n} \zeta(k+1)\zeta(2n-k+2)$$
>   $$-(2n)!\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}\right)\zeta(2k)\zeta(2n-2k+3) + \frac{1}{2^{2n+3}} (2n+3-2^{2n+3})(2n)!\zeta(2n+3),$$
>   and the result is obtained by exploiting the series representation of $\log(1-x)\log(1+x)$.

**A second note:** By the strategy presented above more interesting integrals may be calculated (without Beta function, harmonic series). Another nice example is

> $$\int _0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log(x)\log(1+x)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x$$
>   $$=\frac{17 }{16}\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(2)\zeta(2)+\frac{7}{8} \log (2)\zeta (3) -\frac{1}{12} \log ^4(2)-2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$$

**A second solution in large steps** (we circumvent the use of harmonic series)

If we use the algebraic identities $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$ and $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ which we combine with clever rearrangements of the resulting integrals, we arrive at

$$ \int _0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log(x)\log(1+x)}{x}\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\log(1+x)}{1+x}\textrm{d}x-\frac{3}{8}\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x)\log^2(x)}{1-x}\textrm{d}x}_{\text{Beta function}},$$
where the first integral is calculated in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**, on pages $503-505$, and the second integral is a form of Beta function.

Comment: This is magic. (+1).

Comment: @AliShather Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)\log(1-x)\log(x)}{x}dx$$

Let's rewrite the integral using the following fact:

$$\color{blue}{\log(1+x)\log(1-x)=\frac{\log^2(1-x^2)-\log^2(1-x)-\log^2(1+x)}{2}}$$

$$I=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(1-x^2)\log(x)}{x}}_{x^2\rightarrow x}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log(x)}{x}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(1+x)\log(x)}{x}}_{1+x\rightarrow x}dx$$

$$I=-\frac{3}{8}\int_0^1\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log(x)}{x}}_{x\rightarrow 1-x}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^2\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(x)\log(x-1)}{x-1}}_{x\rightarrow \frac{1}{x}}dx$$

$$I=\underbrace{-\frac{3}{8}\int_0^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx}_{I_1}\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)-\log^3(x)}{x(1-x)}dx}_{I_2}$$

To solve $I_1$ let's use Differentiation Under the Integral Sign, then let's switch the order of integration and apply partial fractions:

$$I_1=\frac{3}{8}\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-y}\int_0^1\left[\frac{\log^2(x)}{1-x}-\frac{\log^2(x)}{1-yx}\right]dxdy=\frac{3}{4}\int_0^1\left[\frac{Li_3(1)-Li_3(y)}{1-y}-\frac{Li_3(y)}{y}\right]dy$$

$$I_1=\frac{3}{4}\left[-\left(Li_3(1)-Li_3(y)\right)\log(1-y)-Li_4(y)\right]^1_0-\frac{3}{4}\int_0^1\frac{Li_2(y)\log(1-y)}{y}dy$$

$$I_1=-\frac{3}{4}Li_4(1)+\frac{3}{8}Li^2_2(1)=\frac{3}{16}\zeta(4)$$

$$\color{red}{I_1=\frac{3}{16}\zeta(4)}$$

To solve $I_2$ let's apply partial fractions and then solve the resulting integrals. Most of them are straightfoward, but one of them requires some algebric work:

$$I_2=-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^1\left[\frac{\log^2{\left(x\right)}\log{\left(1-x\right)}-\log^3{\left(x\right)}}{x}+\frac{\log^2{\left(x\right)}\log{\left(1-x\right)}-\log^3{\left(x\right)}}{1-x}\right]dx$$

$$I_2=\frac{1}{2}\left[Li_2(x)\log^2(x)-2Li_3(x)\log(x)+2Li_4(x)+\frac{\log^4(x)}{4}-\log^3(x)\log(1-x)-3Li_2(x)\log^2(x)+6Li_3(x)\log(x)-6Li_4(x)\right]_{1/2}^1\underbrace{-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2{\left(x\right)}\log{\left(1-x\right)}}{1-x}dx}_{I_{2a}}$$

$$I_2=\frac{1}{2}\left[-4\zeta(4)+4Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+4Li_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\log(2)+2Li_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\log^2(2)+\frac{3}{4}\log^4(2)\right]+I_{2a}$$

$$I_2=-2\zeta(4)+\frac{7\log(2)}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}\zeta(2)+2Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{5\log^4(2)}{24}+I_{2a}$$

Instead of applying Differentiation Under the Integral Sign again to evaluate $I_{2a}$, let's do the following:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
A+B=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx+\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx 
 \\ 
A-B=\int_0^{1/2}\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}}_{x\rightarrow 1-x}dx-\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
A+B=\int_0^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx=-\frac{\zeta(4)}{2} (From\ I_1)
 \\ 
A-B=\int_{1/2}^1\underbrace{\frac{\log^2(1-x)\log(x)}{x}}_{IBP}dx-\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
A+B=-\frac{\zeta(4)}{2} 
 \\ 
A-B=-\frac{\log^4(2)}{2}+\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx -\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Thus
$$B=\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log^2(x)\log(1-x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{\log^4(2)-\zeta(4)}{4} $$
$$I_{2a}=-\frac{B}{2}=\frac{\zeta(4)-\log^4(2)}{8}$$

Hence, gathering all results, it's possible to conclude that:
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\log(1+x)\log(1-x)\log(x)}{x}dx=$$
$$-\frac{27}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac{7log(2)}{4}\zeta(3)-\frac{\log^2(2)}{2}\zeta(2)+2Li_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\log^4(2)}{12}$$

Comment: Thank you :) I just eddited the post following your advices. I hope now that the overbrace thing is no longer an issue.

Comment: (+100 points) Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: OMG, thank you so much for the bounty reward :)

Answer (score 3):

Related problems: [(I)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458852/interesting-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1k-1k2h-k2/469527#469527). You can have the following solution

> $$ \frac{3\gamma}{4}\,\zeta( 3 )+{\frac {7\pi^4}{360}}+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\psi \left( m
>  \right) }{{m}^{3}}}+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty 
> }-{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\psi' \left( m \right) }{{m}^{2}}}\sim 0.2907212779,$$

which you might be able to simplify it further.

**Note:** If you use the identity

> $$ \frac{\pi^4}{90}=\zeta(4), $$

in the above expression, then you will have the form

> $$ \frac{3\gamma}{4}\,\zeta( 3 )+{\frac {7}{4}}\zeta(4)+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty }{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\psi \left( m
>  \right) }{{m}^{3}}}+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty 
> }-{\frac { \left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\psi' \left( m \right) }{{m}^{2}}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align*}
J&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\,dx\\
&\overset{IBP}=\frac{1}{2}\Big[\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)\ln(1+x)\Big]_0^1 -\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \ln^2 x\left(\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}-\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\right)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \ln^2 x\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1-x}-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\right)\,dx\\
K&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{1-x}\,dx,L=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx,M=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)\ln^2 x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&\overset{IBP}=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\ln(1+x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&\overset{u(t)=xt}=2\zeta(3)\ln 2-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2(tx)}{(1-tx)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx\\
&=2\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2(tx)}{(1-tx)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx+\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{t\ln^2(tx)}{(1-tx)(1+t)}\,dt\,dx\right)\\
&=2\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(tx)}{1-tx}\,dt\,dx-\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(tx)}{(1+t)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx\right)\\
&=2\zeta(3)\ln 2+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x+\ln t\ln x}{(1+t)(1+x)}\,dt\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (tx)}{1-tx}\,dt\,dx\\
&=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{144}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 (tx)}{1-tx}\,dt\,dx\\
&\overset{u=tx}=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{144}-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\,dx\\
&\overset{IBP}=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{144}-\frac{1}{2}\left[\ln x\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 u}{1-u}\,du\right)\right]_0^1+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{144}+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{144}+\frac{1}{2}\times -\frac{\pi^4}{15}\\
&=\boxed{\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{19\pi^4}{720}}
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
0&<A<1\\
L(A)&=\int_0^A \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1-x)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&\overset{IBP}=\left[\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\ln(1-x)\right]_0^A+\int_0^A \frac{1}{1-x}\left(\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\,dx\\
&\overset{t(u)=ux}=\left(\int_0^A \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}dt\right)\ln(1-A)+\int_0^A \left(\int_0^1 \frac{x\ln^2(ux)}{(1-x)(1+ux)}\,du\right)\,dx\\
&=\left(\int_0^A \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\ln(1-A)+\int_0^A\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(ux)}{(1+u)(1-x)}du\right)dx-\\
&\int_0^A\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(ux)}{(1+u)(1+ux)}du\right)dx\\
&=\left(\int_0^A \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)\right)\ln(1-A)+\ln 2\int_0^A\frac{\ln^2 x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{\pi^2}{6}\int_0^A \frac{\ln x}{1-x}\,dx-\\
&\int_0^A\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(ux)}{(1+u)(1+ux)}du\right)dx\\
L&=\lim_{A\rightarrow 1}L(A)\\
&=2\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{36}-\int_0^1\left(\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(ux)}{(1+u)(1+ux)}du\right)dx\\
&\overset{t(x)=xu}=2\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{36}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{u(1+u)}\left(\int_0^u \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}\,dt\right)\,du\\
&\overset{IBP}=2\zeta(3)\ln 2+\frac{\pi^4}{36}-\left[\ln\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)\left(\int_0^u \frac{\ln^2 t}{1+t}dt\right)\right]_0^1+\int_0^1 \frac{\ln\left(\frac{u}{1+u}\right)\ln^2 u}{1+u}du\\
&=\frac{7}{2}\zeta(3)\ln 2-\frac{11}{360}\pi^4-M\\
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
U&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)}{1+x}\,dx\\
&\overset{y=\frac{x}{1+x}}=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
U&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx-3\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\,dx+3\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1+x)\ln x}{1+x}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2-3M+\Big[\ln^3(1+x)\ln x\Big]_0^1-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3(1+t)}{t}\,dt\\
&\overset{x=\frac{1}{1+t}}=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2-3M+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{x(1-x)}\,dx\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}\,dx-\frac{1}{4}\ln^4 2-3M+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{x}\,dx-\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x^2}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2-3M-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&=\left(2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx-\int_0^1 \frac{2t\ln^3 t}{1-t}\,dt\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2-3M-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
&\overset{x=t^2}=\frac{15}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\ln^4 2-3M-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
\end{align*}

Therefore,
\begin{align*}
M&=\frac{5}{8}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx-\frac{1}{6}\ln^4 2-\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx\\
\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-x}\,dx&\overset{y=2x}=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)}{1-\frac{1}{2}x}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1-\frac{1}{2}x}\,dx-\frac{\ln^3 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}x}\,dx-\\
&\frac{3\ln 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x}{1-\frac{1}{2}x}dx+\frac{3\ln^2 2}{2}\int_0^1 \frac{\ln x}{1-\frac{1}{2}x}dx\\
&=-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\ln^4 2-6\ln 2\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-3\ln^2 2 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
&=-6\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{21\zeta(3)}{4}\ln 2+\frac{\pi^2 \ln^2 2 }{4}-\frac{\ln^4 2}{2}\\
M&=4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^4}{24}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln 2}{2}-\frac{\pi^2 \ln^2 2}{6}+\frac{\ln^4 2}{6}\\
L&=\boxed{\frac{\pi^4}{90}-4\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{\pi^2 \ln^2 2}{6}-\frac{\ln^4 2}{6}}\\
J&=\frac{1}{2}\left(K-L\right)\\
&=\boxed{2\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{3\pi^4}{160}+\frac{7\zeta(3)\ln 2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2 \ln^2 2}{12}+\frac{\ln^4 2}{12}}
\end{align*}

NB: I assume, $r\geq 1,0< a\leq 1$, integers
\begin{align*} 
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^r x }{1-ax}\,dx&=\frac{(-1)^r r!}{a}\text{Li}_{r+1}(a)\\
\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\ln^2 2}{2},\text{Li}_2(1)=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}\\
\text{Li}_3(1)&=\zeta(3),\text{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{7\zeta(3)}{8}+\frac{\ln^3 2}{6}-\frac{\pi^2\ln 2}{12},\text{Li}_4(1)=\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}
\end{align*}

Comment: (+1) Looks nice.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following variable change.

$$x=e^{-t}$$ Then we can represent the integral as follows:

$$I=-\int_{0}^{\infty}t\ln(1+e^{-t})\ln(1-e^{-t})\;dt$$ Now, apply the Taylor expansion of the logarithm:

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{i-1}\frac{x^i}{i}$$

$$I=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{ij}\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-(i+j)t}dt=$$

$$=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{i-1}}{ij(i+j)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t}\left[B(s+1,t+1)\;_3 F_2(1,1,s+1;2,s+t+2;-1)\right]_{s=t=0}$$

It may be that the Hypergeometric function is summable. In this case, the differentiation is trivial. (B denotes Euler's beta function.)

Comment: Your $LaTeX$ got messed up. Try to fix it.