# What is the closed form of this :$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\log^2(1+x)}{x^s}\,dx$ with $s$ is a complex variable?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

This question is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1341254/555515) , I want to know if it is possible to get a closed form of the below integral with $s$ is  a complex variable $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(x)\log^2(1+x)}{x^s}\,dx$$ ,

Comment: Does the integral even converge unless $2<\text{Re}(s)<3$?

Comment: I think that is converges for 1<Re(s) <3

Comment: Yes, it does.  But it diverges outside that strip.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the integral

$$I(a,b)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^a (1+x)^b}{x^s}\,dx$$
We are then looking for 
$$\frac{\partial^3 I}{\partial a \,\partial b^2 }\Big|_{(a,b)=(0,0)}$$
We can evaluate the first integral in terms of the beta function:

\begin{align}
I(a,b)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{a-s}}{(1+x)^{-b}}\,dx \\
\\
&=\mathcal{B}\left(a-s+1, -(b+a+1)+s\right) \\ 
\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a-s+1)\Gamma(s-(b+a+1))}{\Gamma(-b)}
\end{align}
Letting $m=a-s+1$ and $n=s-(b+a+1)$, we find that

\begin{align} 
\\ \frac{\partial I}{\partial a}&=\frac{\Gamma(m)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(-b)}\left[\psi^{(0)}(m)-\psi^{(0)}\left(n\right)\right] \\
\\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}&= \Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)\left[\frac{\psi^{(0)}(n)+\psi^{(0)}(-b)}{\Gamma(-b)} \left[\psi^{(0)}(n)-\psi^{(0)} (m) \right]+\frac{\psi^{(1)}(n)}{\Gamma(-b)} \right] \\
\\
\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial a \,\partial b^2}&=\,\,...
\end{align}

Comment: is that valid for all complex ?

Comment: I think so yes.

Comment: I think the convergence is only for 1<Re(s)<3, i don't know why you didn't montioned that in your answer

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought you asked it was valid for some complex $s$. Yes, it is restricted to that strip.