# Prove $\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)} dx=7\zeta(4)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-zeta

How to prove, without using beta function that

> $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\ dx=7\zeta(4)$$

where $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

Also, can we take advantage of this result to solve some harmonic series?

Comment: This integral is quite nice! I think I have an idea. Mind sharing the source?

Comment: Sure Zacky go for it .

Comment: I don't see how we can use this result to solve some harmonic series, but as you pointed out, you started with the $(0,1)$ variant of the integral and got this.  That integral basically reduces to finding this harmonic series in disguise: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3324377/515527

Comment: @Zacky neither do I. I was trying to evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^3}$ in a different way but did not work as the $(0,1)$ variant of the integral got cancelled out.

Comment: @Zacky sorry I didnt read your comment "mind sharing the source" carefully, I made it while I was investigating some harmonic series.

Answer (score 14):

Denote the integral by $I$, split up into two parts in the point $1$ and let $x\to \frac{1}{x}$ in the second part to get:
$$I=\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)} dx}+\color{red}{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x \ln(1+1/x)}{1+x}dx}$$
$$\require{cancel}=\color{blue}{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\cancel{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}}+\color{red}{\cancel{\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2 x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx}$$
$$\overset{\color{blue}{IBP}}=\color{blue}{-\frac13\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx}\color{red}{-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx}=\color{purple}{-\frac43\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3 x}{1+x}dx}$$
$$=-\frac43\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \int_0^1 x^{n-1} \ln^3 xdx=8\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^4}=7\zeta(4)$$

Comment: Just a typo. Second line, second integral colored in blue: is it $\ln^2x\ln(1+x)$? I guess you missed $x$ :)

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Yep that's my approach. I was trying to evaluate the boundaries (0,1) version and came across the the post problem .

Comment: Ah, nice! This comment would better fit in the question itself though, in order to bring some context.

Comment: @Zacky just wanted to make the problem shorter :)

Comment: I presume the last part was obtained using: $\eta(s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)$

Comment: @HenryLee of course.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x}
\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x = 7\zeta\pars{4}}}:\ {\Large ?}.\qquad$
$\ds{\zeta}$ is the
[Riemann Zeta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x} =
\int_{1}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x - 1}\ln\pars{x} \over \pars{x - 1}x}\,\dd x 
\\[5mm] = &\
\int_{1}^{0}{\ln^{2}\pars{1/x - 1}\ln\pars{1/x} \over
\pars{1/x - 1}\pars{1/x}}\,\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{\bracks{\ln\pars{1 - x} - \ln\pars{x}}^{\, 2}\ln\pars{x} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{\bracks{\ln\pars{x} - \ln\pars{1 - x}}^{\, 2}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[1cm] = &\
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[1mm] & 
\phantom{=\!} -\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Integrating by parts the last integral in (\ref{1}),

$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x =
3\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}$.

---

(\ref{1}) is reduced to
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
-4\int_{0}^{1}\ \underbrace{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}
_{\ds{-\,\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}}}\
\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x +
2\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{align}

$\ds{\mrm{Li}_{\large s}}$ is the
[Polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

---

$\ds{\large\mbox{Evaluation of}\
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
-\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\,\ln^{2}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{IBP}}{=}\,\,\,&
2\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{2}\pars{x} \over x}\,\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x =
2\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{3}'\pars{x}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x =
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{3}\pars{x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-2\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{4}'\pars{x}\,\dd x =
-2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1} = \bbx{-2\zeta\pars{4}}
\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}

---

$\ds{\large\mbox{Evaluation of}\
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x}$:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x}\ln^{2}\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x} =
\left.{\partial^{3} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu^{2}}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\mu - 1}
\bracks{\pars{1 - x}^{\nu} - 1}\,\dd x\,
\right\vert_{\ds{\mu\ =\ 0^{+} \atop \nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{\partial^{3} \over \partial\mu\,\partial\nu^{2}}
\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}} - {1 \over \mu}}
_{\ds{\mu\ =\ 0^{+} \atop \nu\ =\ 0}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\partiald[2]{}{\nu}\partiald{}{\mu}\braces{
{1 \over \mu}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}\Gamma\pars{\nu + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{\mu + \nu + 1}} - 1}}
_{\ds{\mu\ =\ 0^{+} \atop \nu\ =\ 0}} =
\bbx{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\zeta\pars{4}}
\label{4}\tag{4}
\end{align}

---

Lets replace (\ref{3}) and (\ref{4}) in \ref{2}: 
$$
\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln^{2}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x\pars{1 + x}}\,\dd x} =
-4\bracks{-2\zeta\pars{4}} +
2\bracks{-\,{1 \over 2}\,\zeta\pars{4}} = \bbx{7\zeta\pars{4}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Following the same approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449930/how-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-nn4-by-real-integration-only/3449946#3449946), we can get the generalization

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=(2a)!(2a+2)\left(1-2^{-2a-1}\right)\zeta(2a+2)$$