# How to compute $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}$ by real integration only?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, harmonic-numbers

How to prove, by real methods that

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$$

where $H_n$ is the harmonic number and $\zeta$ is the Riemann zeta function.

This alternating Euler sum was already evaluated by M.N.C.E [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/973408) using complex analysis and also by Cornel using series manipulation. My question here is can we do it by integration only?

The integral representation of the sum is $\ \frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Starting with the generating function:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n=-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{1-x}$$

replace $x$ with $-x$ then multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln^3x}{6x}$ and integrate from $x=0$ to $1$ and use the fact that $-\frac16\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\ln^3xdx=\frac1{n^4}$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}=\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\frac16\mathcal{I}\tag1$$

---

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx}_{x\mapsto 1/x}$$

$$\mathcal{I}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx+\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx$$

By adding $\ \mathcal{I}=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx-\color{blue}{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{1+x}dx}\ $ to both sides, the blue integral nicely cancels out and we get

$$2\mathcal{I}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx+\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x}dx}_{IBP}$$

$$2\mathcal{I}=\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx}_{\text{Beta function:}\ 6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+6\zeta(5)}-\frac54\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1+x}dx}_{\frac{45}2\zeta(5)}$$

or

$$\mathcal{I}=3\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{177}{16}\zeta(5)\tag2$$

---

By plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$ we obtain that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$$

---

**Bonus:**

Following the same strategy, we can come up with two generalizations:

$$i)\int_0^1\frac{\ln^{2a-1}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a-1}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx+\frac{1+2a}2(2a-1)!\operatorname{Li}_{2a+1}(-1)$$

where the $\int_0^\infty$ integral can be done by beta function and $\operatorname{Li}_{a}(-1)=(2^{1-a}-1)\zeta(a)$.

Proof can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451301/an-attempt-to-prove-the-generalization-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-nn) if needed.

$$ii)\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^{2a}(x)\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}dx=(2a)!(2a+2)\left(1-2^{-2a-1}\right)\zeta(2a+2)$$

Its interesting to get the result of $ii$ without using beta function.

---

**Edit**

Details for evaluating $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\ dx$ using beta function can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3538399). Another way  is to start with subbing $\frac{1}{1+x}\mapsto x$

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1+x)}{x(1+x)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\ln x}{1-x}\ dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}-3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}+3\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)}{1-x}}_{IBP}-\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln x\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx}_{IBP}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}-3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}+2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x}}_{\large 1-x\to x}-\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx}_{\large 1-x\to x}$$

$$=\frac34\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{1-x}\ dx$$
$$=\frac34(4!\zeta(5))+\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1 x^n \ln^3x\ dx$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{(n+1)^4}$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}+6\zeta(5)$$

$$=18\zeta(5)-6[3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)]+6\zeta(5)$$

$$=6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+6\zeta(5)$$

Answer (score 3):

**A first way** may be found in the article [A new powerful strategy of calculating a class of alternating Euler sums by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333999069), which presents a very simple way of calculating the general case, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^{2m}}$.

**A second way by Cornel** of getting the result involves the use of a special form of the celebrated Beta function, $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}+x^{b-1}}{(1+x)^{a+b}} \textrm{d}x = \operatorname{B}(a,b)$, as seen in the last part here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3531956.

The extraction of the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^4}$ is achieved immediately by noting that

> $$\lim_{\substack{a\to0 \\ b \to 0}}\frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial a^3 \partial b}\operatorname{B}(a,b)-\lim_{\substack{a\to0 \\ b \to 0}}\frac{\partial^{4}}{\partial a^2 \partial b^2}\operatorname{B}(a,b)$$
>   $$=\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(x)\log^2(1+x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle 15/4\zeta(5)-4\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} H_n/n^4}-\underbrace{\int_0^1 \frac{\log^3(x)\log(1+x)}{x}\textrm{d}x}_{\displaystyle -45/8 \zeta(5)}.$$

To avoid calculating two Beta function limits, one can be easily expressed in terms of the other, and all gets reduced to a classical Euler sum.

**A third way** of getting the value of the series is based on the identity 
$$\int_0^{\infty } \tanh (\pi x)\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=2 H_{2n}-H_n,$$
which is presented in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**. We have to follow a very similar strategy to the one presented in the first part of the solution here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3495138 and we're done (theoretically we can calculate infinitely many series of this type, and far more advance with no touch of complex numbers, like $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^{4}}$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{4n}}{n^{4}}$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{8n}}{n^{6}}$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{16n}}{n^{6}}$, $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{32n}}{n^{8}}$).

**A note**: Very soon a new preprint dealing with this series will appear.