# Fascinating equality

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

The following problem is [proposed](https://www.facebook.com/photo/?fbid=4053819194714848&set=a.222846247812181) by a friend:$$4\int_0^{\pi/4}\left(\int_x^{\pi/4} (x-y)\ln(\tan (x)) \ln\left(\tan \left(y+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)\right) \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x$$
$$-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}  \frac{H_n}{(2 n+1)^4}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1}  \frac{\overline{H_n}}{(2 n+1)^4}$$
$$=\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)G+\frac{15}{16}\ln(2)\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{768}\ln(2)\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right),$$

where $\displaystyle H_{n}=1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ is the $n$th harmonic number and $\displaystyle \overline{H}_n=1-\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$ represents the $n$th skew-harmonic number.

The integral representations for the two sums are:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}  \frac{H_n}{(2 n+1)^4}=\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}dx;$$

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n}  \frac{\overline{H_n}}{(2 n+1)^4}=-\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(x)\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}dx.$$

These two conversions follow from using $\frac{1}{(2n+1)^4}=-\frac16\int_0^1 x^{2n}\ln^3(x)dx$, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} H_n (-x^2)^n=-\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}$, and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \overline{H_n} (-x^2)^n=\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{1+x^2}.$

The first sum was [proposed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160026) by @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze and a closed form (involving hypergeometric function) was [presented](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4160090) by @pisco. About the second sum, I have no idea how to approach it.

The interesting thing about this problem is that when we combine the double integral and the two sums, the closed form comes out nicely with no hypergeometric representation.

Any idea how to prove this equality? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My mind is not blown because I don't know what half of those symbols mean. I'm not asking you to clarify. I'm just dropping in a comment.

Comment: @Adam Rubinson I dont mind clarifying: $G$ is the Catalan constant, $\zeta(.)$ is the zeta function, and $\psi^{(a)}(x)$ is the polygamma function.

Comment: @AliShadhar I would say the title is a bit click-baity, so perhaps it's better to temper it down a notch?