# Show that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}=\frac{5\zeta(3)}{8}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n}=\frac{5\zeta(3)}{8}$$

I tried to create a proof from some lemmas some are suggested by my Senior friends

Lemma 1 $$
{H_n} = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\left( {\frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{{n + k}}} \right)}   = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{n}{{k \cdot \left( {n + k} \right)}}} $$

Lemma 2 $$
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{2n - 1}}}}{{2n - 1}}}  &= \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{n}}  - \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{2n}}}}{{2n}}}  - \log \left( {1 - x} \right) - \frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^{2n}}}}{n}}  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \log \left( {1 - {x^2}} \right) - \log \left( {1 - x} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \cdot \log \frac{{1 + x}}{{1 - x}}
\end{split}
$$

Lemma 3 $$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{\log }^2 x}{1 - x}dx}   & = \int\limits_0^1 {{{\log }^2}x \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{x^n}}   dx} 
\\
&= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\int\limits_0^1 {{{\log }^2}x \cdot {x^n}  dx} }  \\
&= 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{1}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^3}}}}  = 2 \cdot \zeta \left( 3 \right) 
\end{split}$$

Lemma 4 $$
\begin{split}
\int\limits_0^1 {\frac{{{{\log }^2}x}}{{1 + x}} dx} & = \int\limits_0^1 {{{\log }^2}x \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n} \cdot {x^n}} dx}  \\
& = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n} \cdot \int\limits_0^1 {{{\log }^2}x \cdot {x^n} dx} }  \\
& = 2 \cdot \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{{\left( { - 1} \right)}^n} \cdot }}{{{{\left( {n + 1} \right)}^3}}}}  = \frac{3}{2} \cdot \zeta \left( 3 \right)
\end{split}$$

Comment: What did your "Senior friends" say about it? You can ask them again, they will be happy.

Comment: @DietrichBurde At this point, they("Senior friends") are uncertain about what steps to take next :)))

Comment: See the general formula for the Euler sum [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3451301/an-attempt-to-prove-the-generalization-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-nn)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving an alternating Euler sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} H_k}{k} = \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) - \frac{1}{2} \log^2 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk)

Comment: @SilverDoe nice link

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \int_0^1\int_0^1 (-1)^{k-1} (xz)^{k-1}\, \mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}z \int_0^1 y^{n-1} \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-xyz)^{n-1}}{1+xz} \,\mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{(1+xz)(1+xyz)} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}y \,\mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+xz)}{xz(1+xz)} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} \,\mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}z - \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+xz)}{1+xz} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z - \int_0^1 \frac{\log^2(1+z)}{2z} \, \mathrm{d}z \\
&= \frac{3}{4} \zeta(3) - \frac{\zeta(3)}{8} \\
&= \frac{5}{8} \zeta(3)
\end{align}

And for the last row

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{\log(1+xz)}{xz} \, \mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{(-1)^k (xz)^k}{k+1} \,\mathrm{d}x \,\mathrm{d}z = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(k+1)^3} = \frac{3}{4} \zeta(3)$$

Answer (score 2):

Using
$$ \sum_{n=1}^k\frac1n=\int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx $$
one has
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \sum_{n=1}^k \dfrac{1}{n}\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \int_0^1\frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} \frac{1-x^k}{1-x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac1{1-x}\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k^2} x^k\bigg)dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\frac1{1-x}\bigg(\text{Li}_2(-x)-\text{Li}_2(-1)\bigg)dx\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac1{1-x}\int_{-x}^{-1}\frac{\text{Li}_1(t)}{t}dtdx\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac1{1-x}\int_{x}^{1}\frac{\text{Li}_1(-t)}{t}dtdx\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_1(-t)}{t}\int_{0}^{t}\frac1{1-x}dxdt\\
&=&-\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&=&\frac58\zeta(3).
\end{eqnarray}$$
Here
$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+t)\ln(1-t)}{t}dt\\
&=&\frac14\bigg[\int_0^1\frac{\left(\ln(1+t)+\ln(1-t)\right)^2}{t}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\left(\ln(1+t)-\ln(1-t)\right)^2}{t}dt\bigg]\\
&=&\frac14\bigg[\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-t^2)}{t}dt-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2\left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)}{t}\overset{\frac{1-t}{1+t}\to t}{dt}\bigg]\\
&=&\frac14\bigg[\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-t)}{t}dt-2\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2t}{1-t^2}dt\bigg]\\
&=&\cdots
\end{eqnarray}$$

Answer (score 1):

We use a radius circle N+1/2 centered at the origin of the axes as the contour.

We consider the kernel function $$\displaystyle f(z)= \frac{\pi csc(\pi z)(\gamma+\psi(-z))}{z^{2}}$$

There are poles at the positive integers , n, due to the bigamma as well as poles at the negative integers -n as well as at the origin of the axes.

Therefore the series, as $z\to n$ is $\pi csc(\pi z)(\gamma+\psi(-z))$ is

$$\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(z-n)^{2}}+\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}}{z-n}+\cdot\cdot\cdot$$

So the integral remainder is:

$$\displaystyle \lim_{z\to n}\left[Res\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(z-n)^{2}}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)+Res\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}}{z-n}\cdot \frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\right]$$

So we sum the remainders and let Sthe original sum be: (Notice how we get the derivative on the left side due to a double pole)

$$\displaystyle =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-2(-1)^{n}}{n^{3}}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}H_{n}}{n^{2}}$$

$$\displaystyle = \frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)+S............. ......[1]$$

At first we get its coefficient 1/z by simply doing a Laurent expansion of it f(z)to find the residue.

$$\displaystyle \frac{1}{z^{4}}-\frac{\zeta(3)}{z}-\frac{7\pi^{4}}{360}+O(z)$$

So, $Res(f(z),0)=-\zeta(3)............[2]$

In negative integers -nthe order is,
$$\displaystyle \frac{(-1)^{n}(H_{n}-1/n)}{z+n}+......$$

$$\displaystyle \lim_{z\to -n}\left[Res\left(\frac{(-1)^{n}(H_{n}-1/n)}{z+n}\cdot \frac{1}{z^{2}}\right)\right]$$

Add the residues,

$$\displaystyle S-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^{3}}=S+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)............[3]$$

So adding [1]+[2]+[3], and solving for the original series we have:

$$\displaystyle \frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)+S+\frac{3}{4}\zeta(3)+S-\zeta(3)=0$$

$$S=\frac{-5}{8}\zeta(3)$$

Because of $(-1)^{n-1}$ in the original sum we finally get $$\displaystyle \boxed{\frac{5}{8}\zeta(3)}$$