# Quadirlogarithm value $\operatorname{Li}_4 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, polylogarithm

Is there a known closed form for the following

$$\operatorname{Li}_4 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

I know that we can derive the closed of $\operatorname{Li}_1 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right),\operatorname{Li}_2 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right),\operatorname{Li}_3 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$

To put it in an integral representation, the problem asks to solve

$$\int^1_0 \frac{\log(x)^3}{2-x}\, dx$$

Comment: Have you got any solution for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\overbrace{\color{#c00000}{\int_{0}^{1}
> {\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x}}
> ^{\ds{\mbox{Set}\ x \equiv \expo{-t}\ \imp\ t = -\ln\pars{x}}}\ =\
> \half\int_{\infty}^{0}{-t^{3} \over 1 - \expo{-t}/2}\,\pars{-\expo{-t}\,\dd t}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\int_{0}^{\infty}
> t^{3}\expo{-t}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{n}\expo{-nt}\,\dd t
> =-\,\half\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{\half}^{n}
> \int_{0}^{\infty}t^{3}\expo{-\pars{n + 1}t}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\half\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over \pars{n + 1}^{4}}\
> \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{3}\expo{-t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{=\ 3!\ = 6}}\ =\
> -6\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}{\pars{1/2}^{n} \over n^{4}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#66f}{\large%
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{3}\pars{x} \over 2 - x}\,\dd x
=-6\,{\rm Li}_{4}\pars{1 \over 2}} \approx -3.1049
$$

> $\ds{{\rm Li_{s}}\pars{z}}$ is a
>   [PolyLogarithm Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: Thanks Felix. There is a more general formula
$$\text{Li}_s(z)\Gamma(s)=\int^\infty_0 \frac{t^{s-1}}{e^t/z-1}\,dt$$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai That's related to Bose-Einstein statistic. There is a nice appendix about that in [this book](http://www.amazon.com/Statistical-Mechanics-Pathria-Beale/dp/9380931891/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1403629141&sr=8-3&keywords=Pathria).

Answer (score 3):

[Wolfram page on polylogarithms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) says that no closed formula is known for $\mathrm{Li}_n\left(\frac12\right)$ for $n\geq4$, see the remark after their formula (17).

Hence, as I said [answering your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/457395/73025), I would be rather surprised if somebody comes with an answer.

Comment: I still believe there is a closed form .It might involve $\zeta(4), \log^4,\log^3,...$.

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai If anybody will be able to give such a closed form, I will gladly award a bounty to his answer.

Comment: By the way , you might be interested in http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/post968.html#p968 .

Answer (score 3):

Using Borwein paper (1996), the quadrilogarithm value can be expressed by:

$Li_{4} (\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi^4}{360} - \frac{(\log 2)^4}{24} + \frac{\pi^2 (\log 2)^2}{24} - \frac{1}{2} \zeta(\overline 3 , \overline 1) $

Where we introduced the alternate multiple zeta function as:

$\zeta(\overline a , \overline b) = \sum_{m>n>0} \frac{(-1)^{m+n}}{m^a n^b}$

Higher values can be evaluated by multiple zeta functions.

Answer (score 2):

[Related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458852/interesting-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1k-1k2h-k2/469527#469527). You can have the following new identity

> $$\frac{1}{6}\int^1_0 \frac{\log(x)^3}{x-2} dx= \operatorname{Li}_4 \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2\zeta(4) - \operatorname{Li}_4(2)-i\frac{\pi\ln^3(2)}{6}+\frac{{\pi }^{2} \ln^2\left( 2 \right)}{6}-\frac{\ln^4\left( 2\right)}{24}$$

Note that, the above gives a relation between $\operatorname{Li}_4\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)$ and $\operatorname{Li}_4\left( {2}\right)$ which is nice.

Comment: Where did the $14.56\ldots$ come from?

Comment: @RonGordon: I posted the closed form.

Comment: Mhenni, how is this a closed form?  The OP asked for a "closed form" of $\text{Li}_4(1/2)$, and you return $\text{Li}_4(2)$.  No matter what definition we may attribute to the term "closed form," this cannot possibly be it, the relation between the quantities notwithstanding.  Also, what's up with the imaginary piece?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal I would add to Ron Gordon's comment that the expression $\mathrm{Li}_4(2)$ is meaningless, as the standardly defined polylogarithm has a branch cut running from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @RonGordon: Offcourse, it is a closed form and relates two polylogarithm functions.

Comment: @O.L.: Now, you are talking about some thing else which is which branch you need to consider. So, this is an evaluation issue.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Of course. I only want to say that for the expression to make sense, one has to specify the branch. Even so, your statement remains a polylogarithm identity, not a closed form evaluation.

Comment: Let's assume for the moment that @O.L.'s comment is not important and that $\text{Li}_4(2)$ is well-defined.  Even in that case, what you are saying makes no sense.  How is the relationship you allege of any use here?  It is still a series, or an integral, that has to be computed somehow, with the same level of difficulty.

Comment: @RonGordan , I think this is a good thing that Mhenni posted that ,  It is well known to extend the polylogarithm for the value $2$ because we can have nice closed forms . We can get closed forms for $\operatorname{Li}_2(2),\operatorname{Li}_3(2)$ the problem seems to continue with evaluating $\operatorname{Li}_4(2)$

Comment: @ZaidAlyafeai: I am glad you like Mhenni's contribution here.  I disagree that this is a useful solution, though, because this is simply not a closed form for anything.  If the problem were to relate the two values of the polylog, then kudos to Mhenni (although he also never gave a hint as to where such a relationship comes from).  But, that is not the stated problem; rather, it was to ask whether there was a closed form of $\text{Li}_4(1/2)$.  <TBC>

Comment: As O.L. points out, this is extremely unlikely.  Mhenni's solution is **not** a closed form, as it expresses the desired quantity in terms of another that has exactly the same problems of not knowing whether a simple closed form exists.  Actually, it is worse, because now we must define a particular branch cut to make the evaluation even meaningful. This solution replaces one brick wall with another; it provides no insight as to how this quantity is computed practically.