# How can we show that $\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k+1}x\ln(1-x)\over x}\mathrm dx=\Gamma(2k+2) \zeta(2k+3)?$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Motivated by this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/908108/how-to-find-large-int-01-frac-ln31x-ln-xx-mathrm-dx), by a small change we arrived at a simple closed form

> $$\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k+1}x\ln(1-x)\over x}\mathrm dx=\Gamma(2k+2)\zeta(2k+3)\tag1$$
>   $k\ge0$

**How may one prove $(1)?$**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we have

$$ \int_0^1\frac{\log^{2k+1}(x) \log(1-x)}{x}\,dx=\left. \left(\frac{d^{2k+1}}{da^{2k+1}}\int_0^1\frac{x^a\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx\right)\right|_{a=0} \tag 1$$

Then, expanding $\log(1-x)$ is its Mclaurin series, we see that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^a\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+a)}\tag 2$$

Differentiating $2k+1$ times the right-hand side of $(2)$ reveals

$$\frac{d^{2k+1}}{da^{2k+1}}\left (-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+a)} \right)=(2k+1)!\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n+a)^{2k+2}}\tag 3$$

Finally, setting $a=0$ in $(3)$, and using $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^s}$, $s>1$, and $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$, we obtain

$$\int_0^1\frac{\log^{2k+1}(x)\log(1-x)}{x}\,dx=\Gamma(2k+2)\zeta(2k+3) $$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Well done, Mark !

Comment: @Dr MV: i doubt he is a woman.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure. And thank you for the nice comment.  -Mark

Answer (score 1):

Making the change of variables $y=-\ln x$ we get
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^m x\ln(1-x)}{x}\,dx
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\int_0^1\ln^m(x)\, x^{n-1}\,dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n(-1)^m\int_0^\infty y^me^{-ny}\,dy\\
&=(-1)^{m-1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{m!}{n^{m+2}}=(-1)^{m-1} m!\zeta(m+2).
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k + 1}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
> = \Gamma\pars{2k + 2}\zeta\pars{2k + 3}:\ {\large ?}.\qquad k \geq 0}$.

\begin{align}
\mbox{Note that}\quad
\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k + 1}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{2}'\pars{x}\ln^{2k + 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

Lets $\ds{\,\mc{I}_{sn} \equiv \int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{s}'\pars{x}\ln^{n}\pars{x}\,\dd x}$. Then,
\begin{align}
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\mc{I}_{sn}\right\vert_{\ n\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}} & =
-\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{s}\pars{x}\bracks{n\ln^{n - 1}\pars{x}\,{1 \over x}}
\,\dd x =
-n\int_{0}^{1}{\mrm{Li}_{s}\pars{x} \over x}\,\ln^{n - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
-n\int_{0}^{1}\mrm{Li}_{s + 1}'\pars{x}\ln^{n - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x\implies
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\mc{I}_{sn}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-n\,\mc{I}_{s + 1,n - 1}\,,\quad n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 1}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\mbox{and}\ \mc{I}_{s0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{\,\mrm{Li}_{s}\pars{1} = \zeta\pars{s}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k + 1}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-\,\mc{I}_{2,2k + 1} =
\pars{2k + 1}\,\mc{I}_{3,2k} =
-\pars{2k + 1}\pars{2k}\,\mc{I}_{4,2k - 1}
\\[5mm] = & \cdots =
-\pars{2k + 1}\pars{2k}\cdots 1\pars{-\,\mc{I}_{2k + 3,0}} =
\pars{2k + 1}!\,\zeta\pars{2k + 3} =
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{2k + 2}\zeta\pars{2k + 3}}
\end{align}

> Moreover,

\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k + 1}\pars{x}\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\int_{0}^{1}{\ln^{2k + 2}\pars{x} \over 2k + 2}\,
{-1 \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x\ =\ \exp\pars{-t}}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 2k + 2}\int_{\infty}^{0}
{\pars{-t}^{2k + 2} \over 1 - \expo{-t}}\pars{-\expo{-t}}\,\dd t =
{1 \over 2k + 2}\ \underbrace{%
\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{2k + 2} \over \expo{t} - 1}\,\dd t}
_{\ds{\Gamma\pars{2k + 3}\zeta\pars{2s + 3}}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{\Gamma\pars{2k + 2}\zeta\pars{2k + 3}}
\end{align}

> The last integral, in 'line' \eqref{1}, is a
>   [well known $\ds{\zeta}$ function integral representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function)
>   $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{for}\ \Re\pars{k} > - 1~}}$ or/and $\ds{\zeta}$ alternative definition.