# Prove $\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\text{B}(n,m)=-\text{B}(n,m)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+m}$

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative, gamma-function, harmonic-numbers, beta-function

where $\ \displaystyle\text{B}(n,m)=\int_0^1 x^{n-1}(1-x)^{m-1}\ dx=\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n+m)}\ $is the beta function, defined over positive $\ n,m>0$.

The point of this post is to provide a proof for $\ \displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\text{B}(n,m)=-\text{B}(n,m)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+m}$ for, $n$ is a positive integer, so that we can use its' applications as a reference in our solutions and here is some of the applications:

> $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=-\frac{H_n}{n}$$ 
>   $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}}{n}$$ 
>   $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^3(1-x)\ dx=-\frac{H_n^3+3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}}{n}$$
>   $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^4(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n^4+6H_n^2H_n^{(2)}+8H_nH_n^{(3)}+3\left(H_n^{(2)}\right)^2+6H_n^{(4)}}{n}$$

Its worth to mention that the first two identities were obtained by Cornel and can be found in his paper [here](http://files.ele-math.com/articles/jca-08-14.pdf) using simple integration by parts and clever manipulations, but these three identities and more can be found also in Cornel's book, **(Almost) Impossible Integral, Sum, and Series** page $59-63$ using only series manipulations.

Also, Ramya showed in his paper [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/311703645_Evaluation_of_a_cubic_Euler_sum) the first three identities using the derivative of $\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\text{B}(n,m)=-\text{B}(n,m)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k+m}$ which we intend here to prove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(A partial hint/answer but too long for a comment)

I'm not an expert on the subject, but by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Derivatives) one has
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \mathrm{B}(x, y) = \mathrm{B}(x, y) \big(\psi(x) - \psi(x + y)\big)$$
and by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Integral_representations) one has
$$\psi(w + 1) - \psi(z + 1) = H_w - H_z$$
so combining these two seems promising.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
\text{B}(n,m)=\frac{\Gamma(n)\Gamma(m)}{\Gamma(n+m)}=\frac{(n-1)!}{m(m+1)...(m+n-1)}=(n-1)!\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{m+k}
\end{align}
take the log to both sides, we get
\begin{align}
\ln\text{B}(n,m)=\ln(n-1)!+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\ln\left(\frac{1}{m+k}\right)
\end{align}
differentiate both sides with respect to $\ m$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial m}\text{B}(n,m)}{\text{B}(n,m)}=-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{m+k}\quad \Longrightarrow \frac{\partial}{\partial m}\text{B}(n,m)=-\text{B}(n,m)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{m+k}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to prove the three identities in the post using the definition of beta function and its' derivatives.
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \mathrm{B}(n, m)=\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{m-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx = \mathrm{B}(m, n) \big(\psi(m) - \psi(m + n)\big)\tag{1}$$
let $m$ approach $1$, we get

> $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx = \mathrm{B}(n, 1) \big(\psi(1) - \psi(1+n)\big)=-\frac{H_n}{n}$$

Differentiate $(1)$, we get 
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial m^2} \mathrm{B}(n, m)=\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{m-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx = \mathrm{B}(m, n)\left(\left(\psi(m)-\psi(n+m)\right)^2-\psi^{(1)}(m+n)+\psi^{(1)}(m)\right)\tag{2}$$
and by letting $m$ approach $1$, we get

> $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx = \mathrm{B}(n,1)\left(\left(\psi(1)-\psi(1+n)\right)^2-\psi^{(1)}(1+n)+\psi^{(1)}(1)\right)\\=\frac1n\left(H_n^2+H_n^{(2)}\right)$$

Differentiate $(2)$, we get
$$\frac{\partial^3}{\partial m^3} \mathrm{B}(n, m)=\int_0^1x^{n-1}(1-x)^{m-1}\ln^3(1-x)\ dx =\small{ \mathrm{B}(m, n)\left(\left(\psi(m)-\psi(m+n)\right)^3+3\left(\psi^{(1)}(m)-\psi^{(1)}(m+n)\right)\left(\psi(m)-\psi(m+n) \right)-\psi^{(2)}(m+n)+\psi^{(2)}(m)\right)}$$

and by letting $m$ approach $1$, we get

> $$\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^3(1-x)\ dx = \small{\mathrm{B}(1, n)\left(\left(\psi(1)-\psi(1+n)\right)^3+3\left(\psi^{(1)}(1)-\psi^{(1)}(1+n)\right)\left(\psi(m)-\psi(1+n) \right)-\psi^{(2)}(1+n)+\psi^{(2)}(1)\right)}\\=-\frac1n\left(H_n^3+3H_n^{(2)}H_n+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is an integer you can succesively integrate by parts i.e.
\begin{align}
&\quad \, \, \int_0^1 x^{n-1} (1-x)^{m-1} \log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x \\
&=\frac{1}{m} \int_0^1 (1-x)^{m} \left\{ -\frac{x^{n-1}}{1-x} + (n-1)x^{n-2}\log(1-x) \right\} {\rm d}x \\
&= -\frac{B(n,m)}{m} + \frac{(n-1)}{m(m+1)} \int_0^1 (1-x)^{m+1} \left\{ -\frac{x^{n-2}}{1-x} + (n-2)x^{n-3}\log(1-x) \right\} {\rm d}x \\
&= -\frac{B(n,m)}{m} - \frac{(n-1) B(n-1,m+1)}{m(m+1)} \\
&\quad +  \frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{m(m+1)(m+2)} \int_0^1 (1-x)^{m+2} \left\{ -\frac{x^{n-3}}{1-x} + (n-3)x^{n-4}\log(1-x) \right\} {\rm d}x \\
&= \dots \\
&=-\frac{B(n,m)}{m} - \sum_{i=1}^k\frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-i)B(n-i,m+i)}{m(m+1)\cdots(m+i)} \\ 
&\quad + \frac{(n-1) \cdots (n-1-k)}{m(m+1)\cdots(m+k)} \int_0^1 (1-x)^{m+k} x^{n-2-k}\log(1-x) \, {\rm d}x \, .
\end{align}
For $k=n-1$ the last term vanishes, since $\log(1)=0$ in the last boundary term. It is then just a simple matter of fact to use
$$\frac{(n-1)\cdots(n-i)B(n-i,m+i)}{m(m+1)\cdots(m+i-1)} = B(n,m)$$ as can be seen from the Gamma representation.

Answer (score 1):

Following through on @b00n heT's idea, since
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \operatorname{B}(n,m) = \operatorname{B} (n,m) \big{(} \psi (m) - \psi (m + n) \big{)},$$
where $\psi (x)$ denotes the *digamma function*, making use of the fact that $\psi (a) = H_{a - 1} - \gamma$, we see that
\begin{align}
\psi (m) - \psi (m + n) &= H_{m - 1} - H_{m + n - 1}\\
&= \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{m - 1} \right ) - \left (1 + \frac{1}{2} + \cdots + \frac{1}{m - 1} + \frac{1}{m} + \cdots + \frac{1}{m + n - 1} \right )\\
&= -\left (\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{m + 1} + \cdots + \frac{1}{m + n - 1} \right )\\
&= -\sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{k + m},
\end{align}
allowing us to arrive at
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m} \operatorname{B} (n,m) = - \operatorname{B} (n,m) \sum_{k = 0}^{n - 1} \frac{1}{k + m},$$
as desired.

Comment: Nice work Omegadot. I'll provide my solution in couple days.