# Is the result for $3\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^6}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^5}$ known in the literature?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I was able to get the following result

> $$3\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^6}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^5}=11\zeta(3)\zeta(6)+\frac52\zeta(4)\zeta(5)-\frac{13}{6}\zeta^3(3)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-5\zeta(9)$$
>   where $H_n^{(p)}=1+\frac1{2^p}+\cdots+\frac1{n^p}$ is the $n$th generalized harmonic number of order $p$.

based on a nice identity and some manageable Euler sums.  Is this result known in the literature?  Can we evaluate the terms separately?

Comment: I haven't seen this result...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your question, can the sums be evaluated separately? Yes they can. The results for each of these two Euler sums can be found in the 2016 paper [Euler sums and integrals of polylogarithm functions](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/297617367_Euler_sums_and_integrals_of_polylogarithm_functions) by Ce Xu *et al*.

The results are:
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n H^{(2)}_n}{n^6} = \frac{17}{6} \zeta (3) \zeta (6) + \frac{173}{72} \zeta (9) + \frac{1}{4} \zeta (4) \zeta (5) - 3 \zeta (2) \zeta (7) - \frac{2}{3} \zeta^3 (3) \quad \text{(See Eq. 3.18)}$$
and
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n H^{(3)}_n}{n^5} = \frac{679}{24} \zeta (9) - 11 \zeta (2) \zeta (7) - \frac{1}{2} \zeta (3) \zeta (6) - \frac{29}{4} \zeta (4) \zeta (5) - \frac{1}{6} \zeta^3 (3).$$

Answer (score 5):

By the Cauchy product we have,

$$\operatorname{Li}_3^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{12H_n}{n^5}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}-\frac{20}{n^6}\right)x^n\tag{1}$$

Divide both sides of $(1)$ by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1$ to get

\begin{align}
S&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{12H_n}{n^6}+\frac{6H_n^{(2)}}{n^5}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{n^4}-\frac{20}{n^7}\right)=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3^2(x)}{x}\ dx\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\int_0^1x^{n-1}\operatorname{Li}_3(x)\ dx\quad \text{apply integration by parts}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3}\left(\frac{\zeta(3)}{n}-\frac{\zeta(2)}{n^2}+\frac{H_n}{n^3}\right)\\
&\boxed{S=\zeta(3)\zeta(4)-\zeta(2)\zeta(5)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}}
\end{align}

Now multiply both sides of $(1)$ by $\large\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $1$ to get

\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_3^2(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ dx=\frac13\operatorname{Li}_3^3(1)=\frac13\zeta^3(3)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{12H_n}{n^5}+\frac{6H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}-\frac{20}{n^6}\right)\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ dx\quad \text{apply integration by parts}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{12H_n}{n^5}+\frac{6H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}-\frac{20}{n^6}\right)\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}-\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)\\
&=\zeta(2)S-12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^7}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^6}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^5}+20\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^8}
\end{align}
Rearranging the terms and plugging the boxed result of $S$ , we get

$$3\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^6}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(3)}}{n^5}\\=\frac78\zeta(3)\zeta(6)-\frac54\zeta(4)\zeta(5)-\frac16\zeta^3(3)+\frac12\zeta(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}-6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^7}+10\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^8}\tag{2}$$

We have

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^6}=4\zeta(7)-\zeta(2)\zeta(5)-\zeta(3)\zeta(4)\tag{3}$$

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k}{k^8}=5\zeta(9)-\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-\zeta(3)\zeta(6)-\zeta(4)\zeta(5)\tag{4}$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^7}=-\zeta(2)\zeta(7)-\frac72\zeta(3)\zeta(6)+\frac13\zeta^3(3)-\frac{5}{2}\zeta(4)\zeta(5)+\frac{55}{6}\zeta(9)\tag{5}$$

The results of $(3)$ and $(4)$ can be obtained from Euler's identity and the result of $(5)$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3311168).

By substituting the results of $(3)$, $(4)$ and $(5)$ in $(2)$, we get our closed form.

.

---

Special thanks to Cornel for showing us how to expand these polylogarithms using Cauchy product. More such polylogarithmic identities can be found in his book , ***Almost Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series***.