# Triple Euler sum result $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k^{(2)}H_k }{k^2}=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\zeta(5)$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

In the following [thread](http://mathhelpboards.com/calculus-10/generalization-triple-higher-power-polylog-integrals-8044.html)

I arrived at the following result

$$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k^{(2)}H_k }{k^2}=\zeta(2)\zeta(3)+\zeta(5)$$

Defining

$$H_k^{(p)}=\sum_{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n^p},\,\,\, H_k^{(1)}\equiv H_k $$

But, it was after long evaluations and considering many variations of product of polylogarithm integrals.

I think there is an easier approach to get the solution, any ideas ?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/606070/

Comment: @Grigory M. That was my topic and the link of the paper I provided there gave a citation to a paper by Borwein and R. Girgensohn, 'Evaluation of triple Euler sums paper'. The question in hand is a special case of a general formula but I was wondering whether we can solve it without that. The author used combintorics which seemed complicated for me.

Comment: This is a really hard nut to crack. I only noticed this question yesterday, and I have made several attempts, but I still haven't found the proper approach.

Comment: Not an answer, but mathematica returns: $$\frac{\pi ^2 \zeta (3)}{3}-\frac{\gamma \pi ^4}{120},$$ which appears different (in particular, sadly lacking in $\zeta(5)$), and lest we hope that we discovered an amazing identity the two numbers are numerically quite different. Now, the Mathematica NSum[] evaluates the sum as $3.014\dots,$ indicating that its own symbolic evaluation is wrong!(and your formula is correct).

Comment: I verified the given sum as $3.014232105440666044528$ whereas your value is $3.486058256855878404094$

Comment: Please post the symbolic input you entered.

Comment: @robjohn , there is even a more challenging one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/618256/double-euler-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frach-k2-h-kk3.

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}H_n}{n^2}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}$ can be evluated together using two nice identities and in a very short way.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's a derivation that, while fairly long, is self-contained and uses only basic series manipulation techniques, like partial fractions decomposition, telescoping, swapping the order of summation, etc.  It leans heavily on ideas from Borwein and Girgensohn's paper "[Evaluation of Triple Euler Sums](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v3i1r23/pdf)" (*Electronic Journal of Combinatorics* **3**(1) 1996).

First, some notation.  Define the multiple zeta functions by
\begin{align}
\zeta_N(a) &= \sum_{x=1}^N \frac{1}{x^a}, \:\:\: \zeta_N(a,b) = \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^a y^b}, \:\:\: \zeta_N(a,b,c) = \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^b z^c}, \\
\zeta(a,b) &= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^a y^b}, \:\:\: \zeta(a,b,c) = \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^b z^c}.
\end{align}

We will need the following symmetry relation, as well as expressions for $\zeta(4,1)$ and $\zeta(2,2,1) + \zeta(2,1,2)$.  Proofs for all of these are given at the end of the post.
\begin{align}
\zeta_N(a,b) + \zeta_N(b,a) &= \zeta_N(a) \zeta_N(b) - \zeta_N(a+b) \tag{1}\\
\zeta(4,1) &= \zeta(5) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) \tag{2}\\
\zeta(2,2,1) + \zeta(2,1,2) &= \zeta(2,3) + \zeta(3,2) \tag{3}
\end{align}

Given these, we have

**The Main Proof:**
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_k H_k}{k^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_{k-1} H_{k-1}}{k^2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_{k-1}}{k^3} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{k-1}}{k^4} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^5} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_{k-1} H_{k-1}}{k^2} + \zeta(3,2) + \zeta(4,1) + \zeta(5).
\end{align}
The most complicated sum is the first, so let's look at that more closely.
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_{k-1} H_{k-1}}{k^2} &= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} \zeta_{k-1}(2) \zeta_{k-1}(1) \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} (\zeta_{k-1}(2,1) + \zeta_{k-1}(1,2) + \zeta_{k-1}(3)), \text{ by (1)} \\
&= \zeta(2,2,1) + \zeta(2,1,2) + \zeta(2,3), \text{ by definition of the multiple zeta functions} \\
&= 2\zeta(2,3) + \zeta(3,2), \text{ by (3)}.
\end{align}
Thus
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H^{(2)}_k H_k}{k^2} &= 2 \zeta(2,3) + \zeta(3,2) + \zeta(3,2) + \zeta(5) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \zeta(5), \text{ by (2)} \\
&= \zeta(2,3) + \zeta(3,2) + 2 \zeta(5) \\
&= \zeta(2) \zeta(3) - \zeta(5) + 2 \zeta(5), \text{ by (1)} \\
&= \zeta(2) \zeta(3) + \zeta(5).
\end{align}

---

---

**Proof of (1)**: 
\begin{align}
\zeta_N(a,b) + \zeta_N(b,a) &= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^a y^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^b y^a} \\
&= \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{x=y+1}^N \frac{1}{x^a y^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^b y^a}, \\
& \:\:\:\:\:\: \text{ swapping the order of summation on the first sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=x+1}^N \frac{1}{y^a x^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^b y^a}, \text{ relabeling variables on the first sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^N \frac{1}{y^a x^b} - \sum_{x=1}^N \frac{1}{x^{a+b}}, \text{ combining sums} \\
&= \zeta_N(a) \zeta_N(b) - \zeta_N(a+b). \square
\end{align}

**Proof of (2)**:
\begin{align}
\zeta(4,1) &= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^4 y} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^4 (x-y)}, \text{ reindexing the second sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \left(-\frac{1}{x^4 y} - \frac{1}{x^3 y^2} - \frac{1}{x^2y^3} - \frac{1}{x y^4} + \frac{1}{(x-y)y^4}\right), \\
&\:\:\:\:\: \text{ by partial fractions decomposition}\\
&= - \zeta(4,1) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \left(\frac{1}{(x-y)y^4} - \frac{1}{x y^4}  \right) \\
&= - \zeta(4,1) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{y^4} \left(\frac{1}{x-y} - \frac{1}{x}  \right) \\
&= - \zeta(4,1) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^4} \sum_{x=y+1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x-y} - \frac{1}{x}  \right), \\
& \:\:\:\:\: \text{ swapping the order of summation} \\
&= - \zeta(4,1) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^4} \sum_{x=1}^y \frac{1}{x}, \text{ as the sum telescopes} \\
&= - \zeta(4,1) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3) + \zeta(4,1) + \zeta(5) \\
&= \zeta(5) - \zeta(3,2) - \zeta(2,3). \square
\end{align}

For the proof of (3), we need the following additional symmetry result:
\begin{equation}
\zeta_N(a,b,c) + \zeta_N(a,c,b) + \zeta_N(c,a,b) = \zeta_N(c) \zeta_N(a,b) - \zeta_N(a,b+c) - \zeta_N(a+c,b) \tag{4}
\end{equation}

**Proof of (4)**:
\begin{align}
&\zeta_N(a,b,c) + \zeta_N(a,c,b) + \zeta_N(c,a,b) \\
&=\sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^b z^c} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^c z^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b}  \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{x-1} \sum_{y=z+1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^a y^b z^c} + \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{x=y+1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^c z^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\:\text{ swapping order of summation on the first two sums} \\
&= \sum_{z=1}^N \sum_{x=z+1}^N \sum_{y=z+1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^a y^b z^c} + \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{x=y+1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^a y^c z^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\:\text{ swapping order of summation on the first sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=x+1}^N \sum_{z=x+1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=x+1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{x-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\: \text{ relabeling variables on the first two sums} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=x+1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b} - \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=x+1}^N \frac{1}{x^{b+c} y^a} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1}\frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\: \text{ combining the first two sums} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^c y^a z^b} - \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^{a+c} z^b} - \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{x=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^{b+c} y^a}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\:\text{ combining the first and third sums and swapping the order of summation on the second} \\
&= \zeta_N(c) \zeta_N(a,b) - \zeta_N(a+c,b) - \zeta_N(a,b+c). \square
\end{align}

**Proof of (3)**:
\begin{align}
\zeta_N(2,2,1) &= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^2 y^2 z} \\
&=  \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^2 y^2 (y-z)}, \text{ reindexing on the third sum} \\
&=  \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \left( -\frac{1}{x^2 y z^2} - \frac{1}{x^2 y^2 z} + \frac{1}{x^2(y-z)z^2} \right), \\
&\:\:\:\:\: \text{ by partial fractions decomposition} \\
&= - \zeta_N(2,1,2) - \zeta_N(2,2,1) +  \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^2(y-z)z^2} \tag{5}. \\
\end{align}
Now, let's look at the third expression in (5).
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x^2(y-z)z^2} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{x-y-1} \frac{1}{x^2(x-y-z)z^2}, \text{ reindexing the second sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=y+1}^{x-1} \frac{1}{x^2(x-z)(z-y)^2}, \text{ reindexing the third sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{x-1} \sum_{y=1}^{z-1} \frac{1}{x^2(x-z)(z-y)^2}, \text{ swapping the order of summation} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{x-1} \sum_{y=1}^{z-1} \frac{1}{x^2(x-z)y^2}, \text{ reindexing the third sum} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{x-1} \sum_{y=1}^{z-1} \left(-\frac{1}{x y^2 z^2} - \frac{1}{x^2 y^2 z} + \frac{1}{(x-z)y^2 z^2} \right), \text{ by partial fractions decomposition} \\
&= - \zeta_N(1,2,2) - \zeta_N(2,1,2) + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{(x-y)y^2 z^2} \tag{6}, \text{ relabeling variables}.
\end{align}
Let's look at the third expression in (6).
\begin{align}
&\sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{(x-y)y^2 z^2} \\
&= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=1}^{x-1} \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{(x-y)y^2 z^2} + \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2} - \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2} \\
&= \left(\sum_{x=1}^N \frac{1}{x}\right) \left(\sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{y^2 z^2} \right) - \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2}, \\
&\:\:\:\:\: \text{ via the finite sum version of the Cauchy product} \\
&= \zeta_N(1) \zeta_N(2,2) - e_N(1,2,2), \tag{7} \\
\end{align}
where
$$e_N(1,2,2) = \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2}.$$
Putting (5), (6), and (7) together, we have
\begin{align}
\zeta_N(2,2,1) =& - \zeta_N(2,1,2) - \zeta_N(2,2,1) - \zeta_N(1,2,2) - \zeta_N(2,1,2) + \zeta_N(1) \zeta_N(2,2) \\
&- e_N(1,2,2), \\
\zeta_N(2,2,1) + \zeta_N(2,1,2) &= - \zeta_N(1) \zeta_N(2,2) + \zeta_N(2,3) + \zeta_N(3,2) + \zeta_N(1) \zeta_N(2,2) \\
&- e_N(1,2,2), \text{ by (4)} \\
=& \zeta_N(2,3) + \zeta_N(3,2) - e_N(1,2,2). \\
\end{align}
All that remains to complete the proof of (3) is to show that $e_N(1,2,2) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.  We have
\begin{align}
e_N(1,2,2) &= \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^{y-1} \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2} \\
&\leq \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \sum_{z=1}^N \frac{1}{x y^2 z^2} \\
&= \zeta_N(2) \sum_{x=1}^N \sum_{y=N+1-x}^N \frac{1}{x y^2} \\
&= \zeta_N(2) \sum_{y=1}^N \sum_{x=N+1-y}^N \frac{1}{x y^2}, \text{ swapping the order of summation} \\
&\leq \zeta_N(2) \sum_{y=1}^N \frac{1}{y^2} \sum_{x=N+1-y}^N \frac{1}{N+1-y}  \\
&= \zeta_N(2) \sum_{y=1}^N \frac{1}{y^2} \frac{y}{N+1-y} \\
&= \zeta_N(2) \sum_{y=1}^N \frac{1}{y (N+1-y)}\\
&= \zeta_N(2) \frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{y=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{N+1-y} \right), \text{ by partial fractions decomposition} \\
&= \zeta_N(2) \frac{2}{N+1} \zeta_N(1),
\end{align}
which goes to $0$ as $N \to \infty$, since $\zeta_N(1) = O(\log N)$ and $\zeta_N(2) = O(1)$. $\square$

Comment: I just spent two hours typesetting this, and I'm tired of looking at it.  If you spot any typos, let me know, and I'll fix them when I get the chance.

Comment: Hey thanks. I really appreciate that time you spent on that . Just as a note : It can be proved that the complexity of evaluating that sum is equivalent to that of $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k^2}{k^3}$$

Comment: (+1) I was trying to solve this, but I am taking a break for a while. I did come up with some nice relations for double Euler Sums. I can now compute $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n^b}$, so I consider the work I've done on this problem productive.

Comment: @robjohn have you posted your solution for $\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(a)}}{n^b}$ ? I found one proof in some article ( i forgot the name) where they used matrices. It was really boring and complicated. Their work is appreciated though.

Answer (score 21):

Consider the integral $$I= - \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} (\sin^{-1} x)^4 \,dx.$$

Since $$(\sin^{-1} x)^4 = \frac32 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{2^{2n} H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}} \,x^{2 n} \tag{1}$$
and 
$$-\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} x^{2n}\,dx= \frac{\pi}{2} \binom{2n}{n} \frac{(H_n + 2\ln2)}{2^{2n}}, \tag{2}$$

we have 
$$\begin{align*}  
&I= - \frac32 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \cfrac{2^{2n} H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2 \binom{2n}{n}} \int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} x^{2n}\,dx
\\&= \frac{3 \pi}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^2} ( H_n +2 \ln2 )
\\& = \frac{\pi^5}{80} \ln2 + \frac{3 \pi}{4} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}\,H_n}{n^2}.
\end{align*}$$

However, substituting $x\mapsto \sin x$ and employing the [fourier expansion of $\ln \cos x$:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos?noredirect=1&lq=1)
$$\begin{align*}
& I= -2 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^4 \, \ln\cos x\, dx
\\&= 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} x^4 \left(\ln2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \cos(2 x n)}{n} \right)dx
\\&=  \frac{\pi^5}{80}\ln2  + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \int_0^{\pi/2} x^4 \cos(2 x n) dx
\\&= \frac{\pi^5}{80}\ln2 + 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\left(\frac{\pi^3}{8}-\frac{3 \pi}{4 n^2}\right)
\\&= \frac{\pi^5}{80}\ln2 + \frac{\pi^3}{4}\zeta(3) - \frac{3 \pi}{2} \zeta(5). \end{align*}$$

Therefore,

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}\,H_n}{n^2} = 2\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)-2\zeta(5).$$

Finish off using [Euler's formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469023/generalized-euler-sum-sum-n-1-infty-frach-nnq?noredirect=1&lq=1) for $\sum H_n/n^q $.

---

**Notes.**

You may find a proof of $(1)$ [here](https://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Reihenentwicklungen#4.5), and $(2)$ is just the derivative of a beta function. The swap of the sum and the integral should be justified.

I found this proof while exploring series involving $H_n^{(2)}$. Using the same method, I also obtained the following
related results:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}\,H_{2n}}{n^2} =\frac{11}{4}\zeta(2)\,\zeta(3)-\frac{47}{16}\zeta(5) \tag{3}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}\,H_{n}^2}{n^2} = 4 \zeta(3)^2 - \frac{5}{8} \zeta(6) \tag{4}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_n \left(H_{n-1}^{(2)2}-H_{n-1}^{(4)}\right)}{n^2} = 3\,\zeta(3)\,\zeta(4)-4\,\zeta(2)\,\zeta(5)+4\,\zeta(7) \tag{5}$$
and others.

Comment: (+1) The Taylor series for $\left(\arcsin x\right)^4$ is a little gem and I have just realized how horribly efficient this approach is for tackling $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\zeta(2)-H_k^{(2)}\right)^3.$$ Congrats.

Comment: awesome solution. rich of info

Answer (score 14):

I think it is reasonable to start with:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k^{(2)}H_k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^4}+\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}\sum_{1\leq j< k}\frac{1}{j^2},\tag{1}$$
that leads to:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k^{(2)}H_k}{k^2}=\left(\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{j^2}\right)-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{1\leq j< k}\frac{H_j}{j^2},\tag{2}$$
Now since:
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k}{k}x^k,\tag{3}$$
$$\frac{\log^2(1-x)}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_{k-1}}{k}x^k,\tag{4}$$
follows. By dividing by $x$ and integrating between $0$ and $1$ we get:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_{k-1}}{k^2}=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(x)}{1-x}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{u^2}{e^u-1}du=\zeta(3),\tag{5}$$
so:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k^{(2)}H_k}{k^2}=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{1\leq j< k}\frac{H_j}{j^2}.\tag{6}$$
For the last term consider:
$$-\frac{\log(1-xy)}{y(1-xy)}=\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}H_k x^k y^{k-1}, \tag{7}$$
multiply both terms by $-\log(y)$ and integrate between $0$ and $1$ with respect to $y$:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(y)\log(1-xy)}{y(1-xy)}dy = \sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{H_k}{k^2}x^k.\tag{8}$$ 
Multiplying both sides by $-\frac{\log x}{1-x}$ and integrating between $0$ and $1$ with respect to $x$ should do the trick. For the last part it is only required to find an appropriate birational diffeomorphism of the unity square that puts the integral in a nicer form - a sort of "reverse Viola-Rhin method".

Answer (score 6):

We are going to evaluate our sum by establishing a system of two relations.

Lets establish the first relation and using the derivative of beta function ( see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3292603)) , we have
$$-\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^3(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n^3}{n}+3\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n}+2\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}$$
divide both sides by $n$ then take the sum with respect to $n$, we get
\begin{align}
R_1&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n}\ dx\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4(1-x)}{x}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x}\ dx=24\zeta(5)
\end{align}
Then $$\boxed{R_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}+3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=24\zeta(5)}$$

---

To get the second relation, we need to use the sterling number formula ( check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind))
$$ \frac{\ln^k(1-x)}{k!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^k \begin{bmatrix} n \\  k \end{bmatrix}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
letting $k=4$ and using $\displaystyle\begin{bmatrix} n \\  4 \end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{3!}(n-1)!\left[\left(H_{n-1}\right)^3-3H_{n-1}H_{n-1}^{(2)}+2H_{n-1}^{(3)}\right],$ we get $$\frac14\ln^4(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$
differentiate both sides with respect to $x$, we get
$$-\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{1-x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(H_n^3-3H_nH_n^{(2)}+2H_n^{(3)}\right)$$

multiply both sides by $\ln x/x$ then integrate with respect to $x$, we get
\begin{align}
R_2&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3(1-x)\ln x}{x(1-x)}\ dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x\ln(1-x)}{x(1-x)}\ dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln^3x\ dx=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=18\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)
\end{align}
Then $$\boxed{R_2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=18\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)}$$
now we are ready to calculate our sum:
$$R_1-R_2=6\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=6\zeta(5)+6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$
or

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

**And as a bonus**:
$$R_1+R_2=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}=42\zeta(5)-6\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}$$
using the definition of $H_n^{(3)}$ and the partial fraction decomposition, its easy to prove $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{11}2\zeta(5)-2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$
which follows

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^3}{n^2}=10\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Comment: (+1) Good way to do it.

Comment: Thank you glad you like it.

Answer (score 2):

A neat way of dealing with the series by series manipulations (no use of integrals at all) and that circumvents all single harmonic series except the ones of the type $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_n}{n^m}$ may be found in the book  ***[(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783030024611)*** pages $398-401$ (definitely one of the best solutions in the book that is worth seeing).

Comment: Cornel always has the most unique elegant solutions and I learned a lot from him. He is a good friend of mine.

Comment: @AliShather He told me you are a great talent in the work with these series. I work hard to enter the same league. :)

Comment: thank you. its fun man you will like it but it requires a lot of patience

Answer (score 2):

Lets start with the following double sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2(n+k)^2}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}\left(-\int_0^1 x^{n+k-1}\ln xdx\right)$$

$$=-\int_0^1 \ln x\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{k-1}\right)\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}x^n\right)dx$$

$$=-\int_0^1 \ln x\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\left(\frac12\int_0^x \frac{\ln^2(1-y)}{y}dy\right)dx$$

$$=-\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-y)}{y}\left(\int_y^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x}dx\right)dy$$

$$=\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2(1-y)\text{Li}_2(1-y)}{y}dy\overset{1-y=x}{=}\frac12\int_0^1 \frac{\ln^2x\text{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx$$

$$=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_n^{(2)}\int_0^1 x^n \ln^2xdx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{(n+1)^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}^{(2)}}{n^3}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}^{(2)}}{n^3}-\zeta(5)\tag1$$

On the other hand and by writing $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(n+k)^2}=\zeta(2)-H_n^{(2)}$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2(n+k)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}\left(\zeta(2)-H_n^{(2)}\right)$$

$$=\zeta(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}\tag2$$

$(1)-(2)$ gives us

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}=\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

where the last sum follows from dividing both sides of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n}x^n=\frac12\ln^2(1-x)$ by $x$ then $\int_0^1$ , i.e

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n-1}}{n^2}=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1-x}dx=\zeta(3)$$

Comment: (+1) for the work with integrals. The double sum you start with (the version with $H_n$ in the numerator) is a critical sum that appears in the calculations by series manipulations presented in **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series** (see the top of page $399$).

Comment: @user97357329 thank you :) . its good to see you back I think you've been away from this site for quite awhile.

Comment: very rarely around. Looks like you lately have learned a lot and become a king in the realm of harmonic series on MSE. ;)

Comment: @user97357329 I would like to see you participate in solving problems here and also in posting nice questions I learned nice tricks from your postings/solutions. Yes, thank you I've been practicing a lot lately and when i get stuck with something I ask Cornel  he is the real king :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a shorter solution

By Cauchy product we have

$$\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac3{n^3}\right)x^n$$

multiply both sides by $\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=1$ and use the fact that $-\int_0^1x^{n-1}\ln(1-x)\ dx=\frac{H_n}{n}$ we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(2\frac{H_n}{n^2}+\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}-\frac3{n^3}\right)\left(\frac{H_n}{n}\right)=\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=I$$

or $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=3\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+I\tag1$$

I proved in [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3493790)

$$\int_0^1\frac{\zeta(2)-\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ln^2(1-x)\ dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}$$

or

$$I=2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}\tag2$$

plugging $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=5\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}-4\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}+2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

Substituting

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}=3\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}=\frac72\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

gives

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_nH_n^{(2)}}{n^2}=\zeta(5)+\zeta(2)\zeta(3)$$

where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^4}$ can be obtained from using Euler identity and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^2}{n^3}$ can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3204618).