# Find identities for $ζ^\star(2,1,2)$ and $ζ^\star(\bar{2},\bar{1},2)$.

Tags: riemann-zeta

Could someone help find identities for these two?

I started with

$ζ^\star(2,1,2)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k^2})\sum_{l=1}^{k}(\frac{1}{l})\sum_{m=1}^{l}(\frac{1}{m^2})$

and

$ζ^\star(\bar{2},\bar{1},2)$ = $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{((-1)^k}{k^2})\sum_{l=1}^{k}(\frac{(-1)^l}{l})\sum_{m=1}^{l}(\frac{1}{m^2})$

but I've only worked on zeta functions with depth 2, so I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: The first is $+\infty$ or undefined, depending on how you take it.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910045.pdf

Comment: @ThomasAndrews did you perhaps misread the summations? The innermost sum has order $\theta(\ell^{-1})$, so the terms on the second sum are $\theta(\ell^{-2})$, and its sum is thus of order $\theta(k^{-1})$, which means that the terms in the outermost sum are $\theta(k^{-3})$ and it's decidedly convergent...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It is because at first the OP wrote $\sum_{l=1}^\infty$

Comment: @reuns D'oh, I should've checked the edit history first. Thank you, and my apologies!

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of patience, summation by parts reduces

$$ \zeta^\star(2,1,2) = \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac{H_l^{(2)}}{l} $$
 to $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_k H_k^{(2)}}{k^2}$, which is [computable through the Maclaurin series of $\arcsin^4(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612181/triple-euler-sum-result-sum-k-geq-1-frach-k2h-k-k2-zeta2-zeta3/1868355#1868355), and
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k^2}\sum_{l=1}^{k}\frac{H_l}{l^2}= 2\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{H_{k+1}H_k^{(2)}}{(k+1)^2}, $$
so the determination of $ \zeta^\star(2,1,2)$ can be considered as already solved by [nospoon](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/219995/nospoon).