# Sum $S=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k H_k}{k^3}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

We know that
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_k}{k^3} = \frac{\pi^4}{72}.$$
Is there a closed form for the sum
$$S=\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k H_k}{k^3}?$$
Mathematica doesn't give anything resembling a closed form and I have no idea if one exists.

Comment: $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{H_k}{k^3} = \sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk^2(n+k)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nk^2(n+k)}+ \sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2k(n+k)}\right) \\= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n,k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2k^2} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^2 = \frac{\pi^4}{72}$$ and for the second part see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k?rq=1).

Comment: See my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275643/proving-an-alternating-euler-sum-sum-k-1-infty-frac-1k1-h-kk/276590#276590) and follow the links and you will find useful techniques.

Comment: Generally speaking,
\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{H_n}{n^3}z^n
=&2{\rm Li}_4(z)+{\rm Li}_4\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)-{\rm Li}_4(1-z)-{\rm Li}_3(z)\ln(1-z)-\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2^2\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)\\
&+\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2(z)\ln^2(1-z)+\frac{1}{2}{\rm Li}_2^2(z)+\frac{1}{6}\ln^4(1-z)-\frac{1}{6}\ln{z}\ln^3(1-z)\\
&+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^2(1-z)+\zeta(3)\ln(1-z)+\frac{\pi^4}{90}
\end{align}

Comment: @M.N.C.E. Thanks, it must have been a pain to TEX that.

Comment: @M.N.C.E. not safe to have $\frac{z}{z-1}$ when lhs series converges for $z = 1$ but rhs does not make sense, best remove euler-transforms and keep $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{H_n}{n^3}x^n = -\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(1-x)^k}{k^2} -\frac{1}{2} \zeta(2)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+\frac{7}{8}\zeta(4)-\frac{1}{4}\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-x)+\frac{1}{4}\zeta^2(2)+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)+\frac{1}{4}\log^2 x\log^2(1-x)+\frac{1}{2}\log x\log (1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\zeta(3)\log x -\log x\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)$$

Answer (score 2):

Since:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1} H_k x^k = \frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x} $$
we have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{H_k}{k+1} x^{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\log^2(1-x), $$

$$ \sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H_k}{k+1} x^{k} = \frac{1}{2x}\log^2(1+x), $$
and since $\int_{0}^{1} x^k\log(x) = -\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$, it follows that:
$$ S=\sum_{k\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{k}H_k}{(k+1)^3}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^2(1+x)\log x}{2x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
for the last integral, Mathematica returns:
$$ S = \frac{\pi ^4}{48}-\frac{\log^4 2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2\log^2 2}{12} -2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\log 2 \tag{2}$$
and since:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{k}\frac{1}{k+1}}{(k+1)^3}=-1+\frac{7\pi^4}{720}\tag{3} $$
it follows that:

> $$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k H_k}{k^3}=-\frac{11\pi ^4}{360}+\frac{\log^4 2}{12}-\frac{\pi^2\log^2 2}{12} +2 \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)\log 2.\tag{4}$$