# Antiderivative of a function involving logarithms and a fraction.

Tags: integration

Let $l\ge 0$ be an integer. Using integration by parts and the definition of the polylogarithm we have found the following identity:
\begin{equation}
\int \frac{[\log(\xi)]^l}{(1+\xi)^2} \log(1+\xi) d \xi = 
\sum\limits_{p=0}^l l_{(p)} \cdot [\log(\xi)]^{l-p} \cdot \phi_p(\xi) \cdot (-1)^{p+1}
\end{equation}
where the functions $\phi_p$ are given as follows:
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi_0(\xi) &:=& \frac{\log (\xi +1)+1}{\xi +1} \\
\phi_1(\xi) &:=& -\text{Li}_2(-\xi )-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(\xi +1)-\log (\xi +1)+\log (\xi )  \\
\phi_2(\xi) &:=& -\text{Li}_3(-\xi )+\text{Li}_3(\xi +1)+\text{Li}_2(-\xi ) (\log (\xi +1)+1)+\frac{\log ^2(\xi )}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(\xi +1) \log (\xi )+\frac{1}{2} i \pi  \log ^2(\xi +1)-\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log (\xi +1) \\
\phi_3(\xi) &:=& -2 \text{Li}_4(-\xi )-\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{\xi }{\xi +1}\right)+\text{Li}_4(\xi +1)+\text{Li}_3(-\xi ) (\log (\xi +1)+1)+
\frac{1}{72} 
\left(
-72 \zeta (3) \log (\xi +1)+
72 \zeta (3) \log (\xi )-
3 \log ^4(\xi +1)+
12 \log(\xi ) \log ^3(\xi +1)+ \\
12 i \pi  \log ^3(\xi +1)+
12 \log ^3(\xi )-
6 \pi ^2 \log ^2(\xi +1)+
72 i \pi  \zeta (3)+\pi ^4
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Here $l_{(p)}:=l(l-1)\cdot \dots \cdot (l-p+1)$ is the lower Pochhammer symbol.

Unfortunately we got stuck at $l=3$ because we lack knowledge about a reflection formula for the polylogarithm of order four and therefore we cannot simplify the terms involving $\mbox{Li}_4$ in the last equation above. Now, the question is therefore twofold. Firstly, what is the generic formula for $\phi_p(\xi)$ when $p\ge 4$ and secondly where can I find the functional identities (reflection formulae) for polylogarithms of order greater or equal to five).