# Generating function of squares of generalized harmonic numbers

Tags: summation, closed-form

Let $x \in [0,1]$. By using the integral representation of a generalized harmonic number and then by integrating by parts we have shown that:
\begin{eqnarray}
\tiny
&&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty [H^{(2)}_n]^2 x^n =\\
&&\frac{360 \zeta (3) \log (x)+60 \pi ^2 \log (1-x) \log (x)+4 \pi ^4}{180 (x-1)}+\\
&&\frac{45 \log ^4(1-x)-90 \log ^2(x) \log ^2(1-x)-30 \pi ^2 \log ^2(1-x)}{180 (x-1)}+\\
&&\frac{-90 \text{Li}_2(x){}^2+180 \text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)+180 \text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}{180 (x-1)}+\\
&&\frac{360 \text{Li}_3(1-x) \log \left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-360 \text{Li}_3(x) \log (x)+360 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \log \left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)}{180 (x-1)}+\\
&&\frac{-360 \text{Li}_4(1-x)+360 \text{Li}_4(x)+360 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)}{180 (x-1)}+\\
&&\frac{1}{1-x}\left(
\zeta\left(\begin{array}{r}2 & 2\\x&\frac{1}{x}\end{array}\right)+
2\zeta\left(\begin{array}{r}3 & 1\\1&x\end{array}\right)+
2\zeta\left(\begin{array}{r}3 & 1\\x&\frac{1}{x}\end{array}\right)
\right)
\end{eqnarray}
where $\zeta\left(\right)$ are multivariate zeta functions (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultivariateZetaFunction.html for the definition).
Now, the interesting question would be is it possible to reduce the later functions to polylogarithms and to elementary functions only?

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I fixed the typo.

Comment: There is a $+$ sign just before the last parenthesis. Probably it should be deleted, or perhaps a term is missing.

Comment: Again, thank you for the review. I again double checked everything and there is no term missing. The plus sign at the end of the line appeared because I just copied and pasted the previous line and then modified it slightly.

Answer (score 1):

In here we show that the middle term can indeed be reduced to polylogarithms. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta\left(\begin{array}{rr}3 & 1 \\ 1 & x \end{array} \right) &:=&
\sum\limits_{\infty > k > k_1 \ge 1} \frac{1}{k^3} \cdot \frac{x^{k_1}}{k_1}\\
&=& \sum\limits_{k_1=1}^\infty \frac{x^{k_1}}{k_1} \cdot\left(\zeta(3) -H^{(3)}_{k_1} \right)\\
&=&-\log(1-x) \cdot \zeta(3) - \int\limits_0^1 \frac{Li_3(\xi)}{\xi(1-\xi)} d\xi \\
&=& -\log(1-x) \cdot \zeta(3) - \left(Li_4(x) - \frac{1}{2} Li_2(x) - \log(1-x) Li_3(x)\right) \\
\end{eqnarray}
Now we tackle the other term:
\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta\left(\begin{array}{r} 2& 2\\x& \frac{1}{x} \end{array}\right) &:=&
\sum\limits_{k_1=1}^\infty \sum\limits_{k=k_1+1}^\infty \frac{x^{k-k_1}}{k^2 k_1^2}\\
&=& \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k \sum\limits_{k_1=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(k+k_1)^2 k_1^2} \\
&=& \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k \left(2\zeta(2) \frac{1}{k^2} -2 \frac{H_k}{k^3} - \frac{H^{(2)}_k}{k^2} \right)\\
&=& 2\zeta(2) Li_2(x) - 2 \sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^3} H_k
-\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2} H^{(2)}_k
\end{eqnarray}
Clearly the first sum on the right hand side has been almost computed here in MSE (see [Alternating harmonic sum $\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^3}H_k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k/1907575#1907575) for example). In fact we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^3} H_k =\\
&&\left\{
\begin{array}{rr}
-\text{Li}_4(1-x)-\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+2 \text{Li}_4(x)-\text{Li}_3(x) \log (1-x)+\zeta (3) \log (1-x)-\frac{1}{24} \log ^4(x)+\frac{1}{6} \log (1-x) \log ^3(x)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^2(1-x) \log
   ^2(x)-\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2 \log ^2(x)+\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log (1-x) \log (x)-\frac{\pi ^4}{120} & \mbox{if $x>0$}\\
\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)+2 \text{Li}_4(x)+\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-\text{Li}_3(x) \log (1-x)+\zeta (3) \log (1-x)+\frac{1}{12} \log ^4(1-x)-\frac{1}{6} \log (-x) \log ^3(1-x)-\frac{1}{12} \pi ^2
   \log ^2(1-x)-\frac{\pi ^4}{90} & \mbox{if $x<0$}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
The remaining sum reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2} H^{(2)}_k = \int\limits_0^x \log(\frac{x}{\xi})\cdot \frac{1}{\xi}\cdot \frac{Li_2(\xi)}{1-\xi} d\xi = \int\limits_0^1 \log(\frac{1}{\xi}) \cdot \frac{1}{\xi} \cdot \frac{Li_2(x \xi)}{1-x \xi} d \xi \\
&&-\int\limits_0^1 \log(\xi) \cdot Li_2(x \xi) \cdot \left[\frac{1}{\xi} + \frac{x}{1-x \xi}\right] d\xi = Li_4(x) + \int\limits_0^1 \log(\xi) \cdot Li_2(x \xi) \left(\frac{-x}{1-x \xi}\right) d\xi =\\
&&Li_4(x) + Li_2^2(x) - \int\limits_0^1 \left[\log(\xi) \cdot \log(1-x \xi)+Li_2(x \xi)\right] \cdot \frac{(-)\log(1- x \xi)}{\xi} d\xi =\\
&& Li_4(x) + \frac{1}{2} Li_2(x)^2 + \int\limits_0^1 \frac{\log(\xi)}{\xi} \cdot \log(1-x \xi)^2 d \xi
\end{eqnarray}
Now, the  integral in the last equation on the right hand side is proportional to the generalized Nielsen polylogarithms. Therefore it can be expressed in terms of polylogarithms as well. The final result reads:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2} H^{(2)}_k =\\
&&-2 \zeta (3) \log (x)-\frac{1}{4} \log ^4(1-x)+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(x) \log ^2(1-x)+\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log ^2(1-x)-\frac{1}{3} \pi ^2 \log (x) \log (1-x)-\frac{\pi ^4}{45}\frac{\text{Li}_2(x){}^2}{2}-\text{Li}_2(x) \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-\text{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{x}-1\right)-2 \text{Li}_3(1-x) \log (1-x)+2 \text{Li}_3(1-x) \log (x)+2 \text{Li}_3(x) \log (x)-2 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \log (1-x)+2 \text{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right) \log (x)+2 \text{Li}_4(1-x)-\text{Li}_4(x)-2 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Now we proceed to compute the remaining term. We carry out the same steps as before, meaning changing the order of summation, collecting all terms corresponding to a given power of $x$ and then decomposing the coefficient at the power of $x$ into simple fractions and then resumming those simple fractions using the definition of harmonic numbers and the zeta function. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
\zeta\left(\begin{array}{rr} 3 & 1 \\ x & \frac{1}{x}\end{array} \right)=
\log(1-x) \cdot \zeta(3) - Li_2(x) \cdot \zeta(2) +
\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k \frac{H_k}{k^3} +\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k \frac{H^{(3)}_k}{k} +\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty x^k \frac{H^{(2)}_k}{k^2}
\end{eqnarray}
As before  the result has been reduced to harmonic sums (those sums are always simpler than the original harmonic sum that we are attempting to compute). Out of the sums on the right hand side only the middle one has not been computed yet. We compute it now:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty x^n \frac{H^{(3)}_n}{n} = \int\limits_0^x \frac{Li_3(\xi)}{\xi(1-\xi)} d\xi = \int\limits_0^x Li_3(\xi) \left[\frac{1}{\xi} + \frac{1}{1-\xi}\right] d\xi =\\
&&Li_4(x) + \int\limits_0^x Li_3(\xi) \frac{1}{1-\xi} d\xi =
Li_4(x) - \log(1-x) Li_3(x) - \int\limits_0^x Li_2^{'}(\xi) Li_2(\xi) d \xi =\\&&  Li_4(x) - \log(1-x) Li_3(x) - \frac{1}{2} Li_2(x)^2
\end{eqnarray}
This finishes the calculation.

Comment: @ Przemo I have calculated $\sum _ {} x^k H_{k} /k^3$ independently, and found a different expression. I confirm that your expression leads to the correct power series at $x=0$ in the range $0\le x \le 1$. But the value at $x= -1$ is not correct as it does not coincide with the numerical calculation of the alternating sum (-0.8527...). My expression gives a real part which coincides with the sum. I believe it is worthwhile to request an expression which represents the analytic function of $x$ in the unit circle (the region of absolute convergence).

Comment: @Dr Wolfgang Hintze: Thank you for this remark. It is likely that I made an error related to the argument of $x$. I will check the calculations and get back to you. What is frustrating about this stuff is that I am not aware of any reflection formula for the polylogarithm of order four and as such going beyond weight four is hard because one needs to deal with a plethora of terms yet the calculations are simple. Do you know any functional identities of the polylogarithms of order four or higher?

Comment: @ Przemo My strategy is to look for expressions which first of all are valid in the whole region -1<x<1 Then I try to split real and imaginary parts. I have the impression that reflexion formulae for $Li_{m}(x)$  exist only for m=2. But we have inversion formulas for any $m$ which ca be used to shift the region of the argument of $Li_{m}(x)$ to $x \lt 1$ where the function is real.

Comment: @Dr Wolfgang Hintze: I have got two expressions for the sum in question , one is valid for positive and one for negative values of $x$. It is simply that I do not know how to add here a link to the Mathematica generated text file. If you want I can send you the file via email.

Comment: @ Przemo What are the limits for $x\to+1$ and $x\to-1$ ? To continue our discussion we could go to a chat room. There one can also upload files like Mathematica code.

Comment: @Dr Wolfgang Hintze: I finally managed to simplify the formulae to such an extent that they now fit into this page.The formulae are above. Thank you for the piece of information about the inversion identities for arbitrary polylogarithms. This was very useful for simplifying equations. And the limits $x \rightarrow \pm $ of course match as they should. Now, I am quite excited about this stuff because it seems quite likely that I will be able to derive higher order generating function,i.e. with higher powers in the denominator.

Comment: @ Przemo  I'm glad that my hints were useful for you. But I am not as optimistic as you are when it comes to higher powers in two senses. I have found (rederived): (i) powers in the denominator: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_{k} x^k}{k^q}$ for q = 1..3 but not for q>=4, and (ii) powers of harmonic function: $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } H_{k}{}^p x^k$ for p = 2..4 but not for p>=5.

Comment: @Dr Wolfgang Hintze: Well, I have derived a "closed form expression" for the former sum for $q=4$ here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544769/another-closed-form-expression-for-a-generating-function-involving-harmonic-nu .As you rightfully pointed out it involves something more than elementary functions and poly-logarithms only.

Comment: @ Przemo I have seen it. Good work! I think we can agree that the linear sums can all be expressed in term of polylog and hypergeometric functions. But these expressions are not very enlightning, and it is also very difficult to derive boundary values from it. And as H^q is concerned: did you see the sum for q=5 somewhere?

Comment: You can find a full proof for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^3}x^n$ here  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482240 .

As for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}x^n$, by Cauchy product  we have 

$$\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(x)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}x^n-3\operatorname{Li}_4(x)$$

Comment: @Dr. Wolfgang Hintze you mentioned that you calculated $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}x^n$, did you post your solution here on MSE?