# How to evaluate $\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

How to find $$\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx\ ?$$

I came across this integral while I was trying to find $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}x^n$ and here is my work,

Divide [the identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^2}x^{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(x)+\zeta(3)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)+\frac12\ln x\ln^2(1-x)$$
by $x$ then integrate from $x=0$ to $x=y $ we get

$$\small{\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^3}y^{n}}=\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\underbrace{\int_0^y\frac{\zeta(3)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)}{x}dx}_{A}+\underbrace{\int_0^y\frac{\ln(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{x}dx}_{B}+\underbrace{\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx}_{C}}$$

---

For the integral $A$, integrate by parts

$$A=\ln y\zeta(3)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)}{1-x}dx$$

$$=\ln y\zeta(3)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-x)|_0^y$$

$$=\ln y\zeta(3)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(1-y)+\frac54\zeta(4)$$

---

Integrate by parts for $B$ too

$$B=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}dx$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(H_n^{(2)}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\int_0^y x^{n-1}\ln x\ dx$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(H_n^{(2)}-\frac1{n^2}\right)\left(\ln y\frac{y^n}{n}-\frac{y^n}{n^2}\right)$$

$$=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}y^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}y^n$$

by Cauchy product we have

$$\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^2}y^n-3\operatorname{Li}_4(y)$$

which gives

$$B=\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n}y^n+2\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n}$$

---

For $C$, if we use $$\frac12\ln^2(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{H_n}{n}-\frac1{n^2}\right)x^n$$

we get

$$C=\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}y^n-\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}
{n^3}y^n}$$

---

Now if we combine the results of $A$ , $B$ and $C$, the red sum will cancel out from both sides and that's why I am trying to find a different way to evaluate $C$ or we can use the result of $C$ but we have to find a different way to evaluate $B$ . any idea?

Thank you,

---

By the way, *mathematica* gives[image]

Comment: You'd be happy to use that $$\log^3(x/(1-x)) =\log^3(x)-3 \log^2(x)\log(1-x)+3 \log(x)\log^2(1-x)-\log^3(1-x).$$

Comment: I think thats the key to solve $C$.. very nice. Thank you

Comment: but what about the first term $\ln^3(x)$? if we divide by $x$ and integrate from zero to y, the integral will diverge at zero. so we better choose a different  boundaries in this case i guess.

Comment: I think another idea is to treat it as indefinite integral.

Comment: Your last idea should work better since you need to cover all values $|x|\le1$. That way you apply the algebraic identity I mentioned above and avoid any possible blown to infinity.

Comment: Yes I picked this way :)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @user97357329 for providing the key identity to solve  the integral $C$,

$$\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) =\ln^3(x)-3 \ln^2(x)\ln(1-x)+3 \ln(x)\ln^2(1-x)-\ln^3(1-x)$$

To have a less messy solution, I am going to evaluate the integral $C$ as an indefinite integral and the integral constant will be ignored as we will plug in the boundaries $0$ and $y$ eventually.

It follows from the identity above that

$$3\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$

$$=\underbrace{\int\frac1{x}\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)dx}_{\Large\mathcal{I}_1}+3\underbrace{\int\frac{\ln^2x\ln(1-x)}{x}dx}_{\Large\mathcal{I}_2}+\underbrace{\int\frac{\ln^3(1-x)}{x}dx}_{\Large\mathcal{I}_3}-\frac14\ln^4x$$

---

For $\mathcal{I}_1$, sub $\frac{x}{1-x}=t$

$$\mathcal{I}_1=\int\frac{\ln^3t}{t(1+t)}dt=\int\frac{\ln^3t}{t}dt-\int\frac{\ln^3t}{1+t}dt$$

$$=\frac14\ln^4t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\int x^{n-1}\ln^3t\ dt$$

$$=\frac14\ln^4t+\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(\frac{\ln^3t\ t^n}{n}-\frac{3\ln^2t\ t^n}{n^2}+\frac{6\ln t\ t^n}{n^3}-\frac{6t^n}{n^4}\right)$$

$$=\frac14\ln^4t-\ln^3t\ln(1+t)-3\ln^2t\operatorname{Li}_2(-t)+6\ln t\operatorname{Li}_3(-t)-6\operatorname{Li}_4(-t)$$

$$=\frac14\ln^4\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)+\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\ln(1-x)-3\ln^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)\\+6\ln \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)$$

---

$$\mathcal{I}_2=-\sum_{n-1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int x^{n-1}\ln^2x\ dx$$

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n\left(\frac{\ln^2x\ x^n}{n}-\frac{2\ln x\ x^n}{n^2}+\frac{2x^n}{n^3}\right)$$

$$=-\ln^2x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)+2\ln x\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(x)$$

---

For $\mathcal{I}_3$, use $1-x=t$

$$\mathcal{I}_3=-\int\frac{\ln^3t}{1-t}dt=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty t^{n-1}\ln^3t\ dt$$

$$=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{\ln^3t\ t^n}{n}-\frac{3\ln^2t\ t^n}{n^2}+\frac{6\ln t\ t^n}{n^3}-\frac{6t^n}{n^4}\right)$$

$$=\ln^3t\ln(1-t)+3\ln^2t\operatorname{Li}_2(t)-6\ln t\operatorname{Li}_3(t)+6\operatorname{Li}_4(t)$$

$$=\ln^3(1-x)\ln x+3\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)-6\ln (1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+6\operatorname{Li}_4(1-x)$$

---

Combine the results of $\mathcal{I}_1$, $\mathcal{I}_2$ and $\mathcal{I}_3$, the terms $\frac14\ln^4x$ and $\ln x\ln^3(1-x)$ nicely cancel out

$$3\int\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$
$$=\frac32\ln^2x\ln^2(1-x)-\ln^3x\ln(1-x)+\frac14\ln^4(1-x)+\ln^3\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\ln(1-x)\\-3\ln^2\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)+6\ln \left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-6\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)-3\ln^2x\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\\+6\ln x\operatorname{Li}_3(x)-6\operatorname{Li}_4(x)+3\ln^2(1-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-x)-6\ln (1-x)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-x)+6\operatorname{Li}_4(1-x)$$

Now plug in the boundaries $0$ and $y$ then divide by $3$ we obtain that

> $$\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$
>   $$=\frac12\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)-\frac13\ln^3y\ln(1-y)+\frac1{12}\ln^4(1-y)+\frac13\ln^3\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln(1-y)\\-\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+2\ln \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\ln^2y\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\\+2\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-2\ln (1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+2\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)-2\zeta(4)$$

---

**Bonus:**

In the question body we have

$$\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx=\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\ln y\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^2}y^n-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}
{n^3}y^n$$

[Substitute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366039/a-group-of-important-generating-functions-involving-harmonic-number)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_{n}}{n^2}y^{n}=\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\frac12\ln y\ln^2(1-y)+\zeta(3)$$

and 
$$\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$$
$$=\frac14\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)-\frac16\ln^3y\ln(1-y)+\frac1{24}\ln^4(1-y)+\frac16\ln^3\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln(1-y)\\-\frac12\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+\ln \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\frac12\ln^2y\operatorname{Li}_2(y)\\+\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(y)+\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)-\ln (1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)-\zeta(4)$$

we obtain that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n$$
$$=\zeta(4)-\frac1{24}\ln^4(1-y)+\frac16\ln^3y\ln(1-y)-\frac16\ln^3\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\ln(1-y)+\frac14\ln^2y\ln^2(1-y)$$

$$-\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\frac12\ln^2y\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\ln (1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(y)$$

$$-\ln y\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\ln y\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(1-y)+\zeta(3)\ln y+2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)$$

$$+\frac12\ln^2\left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\ln \left(\frac{y}{1-y}\right)\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)$$

---

If we use Landen's identity

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=-\frac12\ln^2(1-y)$$

and

$$\operatorname{Li}_3(1-y)+\operatorname{Li}_3(y)+\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)=\zeta(3)+\frac16\ln^3(1-y)-\frac12\ln^2y\ln(1-y)+\zeta(2)\ln y$$

the sum simplifies to

> \begin{align}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{H_n}{n^3}y^n&=\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2\left(\frac{y}{y-1}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_4(y)-\operatorname{Li}_4(1-y)-\ln(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_3(y)\\
> &\quad +\frac12\ln^2(1-y)\operatorname{Li}_2(y)+\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2^2(y)+\frac16\ln^4(1-y)-\frac16\ln y\ln^3(1-y)\\
> &\quad+\frac12\zeta(2)\ln^2(1-y)+\zeta(3)\ln(1-y)+\zeta(4)
> \end{align}

Comment: The calculations are correct. At $y=1/2$ you should get $$1/4 (\log^4(2)-\zeta(4))\approx -0.212872.$$ Apart from this, note the last term on the second row of the closed-form you have $\ln^2 x$ instead of $\ln^2 y$.

Comment: Oh wait I see no error now

Comment: @user97357329 thank you. I checked my steps and forgot about checking the closed form I typed on wolfram for verifying.

Comment: thanks @Edward H