# How to simplify this polylog expression $\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)$?

Tags: integration, special-functions, functional-equations, polylogarithm

Evaluating this integral in Mathematica

$$i_2(z)=\int_0^z \frac{\log ^2(x) \log (1-x)}{1-x} \, dx\tag{1}$$

returns a mixture of polylogs up to order 4 and several log-terms.

In the region of interest $0 \le z \le 1$ we can simplify the expression using the simple functional substitutions

$$\log \left(\frac{1}{z}-1\right)\to  \log (1-z)- \log (z)\tag{2a}$$
$$\log \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\to - \log (z)\tag{2b}$$

and the more sophistcated ones ([1], [2])

$$\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)\to - \operatorname{Li}_2(1-z)-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(z)\tag{3a}$$
$$\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)\to  \left(-\operatorname{Li}_3(1-z)-\operatorname{Li}_3(z)\\
+\zeta (2) \log (z)+\frac{\log ^3(z)}{6}-\frac{1}{2} \log (1-z) \log ^2(z)+\zeta (3)\right)\tag{3b}$$

The expression for $i_2(z)$ now has, in the region of interest, been tranformed to a beautiful form defined as containing only explicitly real terms with simple linear arguments (except for one term) :

$$i_2(z) = -\text{Li}_4(1-z)-\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)+\text{Li}_4(z)+\frac{1}{2} \text{Li}_2(1-z) \log ^2(z)+\frac{1}{2} \text{Li}_2(z) \log ^2(z)-\text{Li}_2(1-z) \log (1-z) \log (z)+\text{Li}_3(1-z) \log (z)-\text{Li}_3(z) \log (1-z)-\zeta (3) \log (z)+\zeta (3) \log (1-z)-\frac{1}{24} \log ^4(z)\\+\frac{2}{3} \log (1-z) \log ^3(z)-\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log ^2(z)-\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(1-z) \log ^2(z)\\
+\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \log (1-z) \log (z)-\frac{\pi ^4}{120}\tag{4}$$

The exceptional "ugly" term left is

$$u_4(z) =\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{z-1}{z}\right)\tag{5}$$

We have seen that for lower order there are functional equations which "beautify" the expression.

Unfortunately, I have neither found a reference in the literature nor have I found the functional transformation myself

**Question:** can you transform $u_4$ to a beautiful form defined above?

**My attempts**

1) Starting with

$$u_4(z)=\int_0^{1-\frac{1}{z}} \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(x)}{x} \, dx$$

Substituting $x\to 1-\frac{1}{t}$ gives

$$u_4(z)=\int_1^z \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{t-1}{t}\right)}{(t-1) t} \, dt$$

The integral on the r.h.s. is readily calculated by Mathematica, but the result which consists of many terms, unfortunately contains exactly $u_4(z)$, i.e. it cancels out. Maybe it is just a trivial tautology. Here I got stuck.

2) Expanding $u_2(z)$ about $z=0$ and trying to guess the result. I wasn't good enough at guessing to find anything resonable up to now.

**References**

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm

[2] https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Trilogarithm.html

Comment: The duplication formula relating $\operatorname{Li}_{n}{(z^2)}$ to $\operatorname{Li}_{n}{(z)}$ and $\operatorname{Li}_{n}{(-z)}$, as well as there inversion formula relating $\operatorname{Li}_{n}{(-z)}$ to $\operatorname{Li}_{n}{(-\frac{1}{z})}$ both extend to all higher orders $n>3$. Together, these guarantee that any polylogarithm with argument $x\le1$ can be rewritten in terms of polylogarithms with arguments inside $[0,1]$, which is progress of a sort towards being less ugly. Beyond that, we'd usually be out of luck....

Comment: @David H Thank you for the hint. Sorry, but obviously I'm too stupid this morning: since $z\in(0,1)$ we have $1-\frac{1}{z} \in (0,-\infty) $, via the duplication formula we can make the argument positive and get $\frac{1}{z}-1 \in (0,\infty) $. But I don't see how to bring this to $(0,1)$ since the inversion formula just tranforms this interval onto intself. What did I miss? I could do it, though, with a case distinction with respect to $z=\frac{1}{2}$ . Did you mean that?

Comment: Yes, this does mean considering the $z<\frac12$ and $z>\frac12$ cases separately to determine whether $w<-1$ or $-1<w<0$, where $w=\frac{z-1}{z}$. If $w<-1$, use the inversion formula before using the duplication formula.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Let's see if the case distinction becomes the ugly part ...

Comment: Another thing I just noticed, your initial integral seems to obey a reflection formula of its own: $i_2(z)+i_2(1-z)-i_2(1)=-\frac12\ln^2(z)\ln^2(1-z)$. So, you could actually go ahead and assume without loss of generality that $0<z\frac12$ or the other way around, if you like.

Comment: That's great! Now I understand what makes $z=\frac{1}{2}$ special here.

Comment: Kindly check the integral $\frac12\int_0^y\frac{\ln x\ln^2(1-x)}{x}dx$ in here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3482240 and to get your integral, just let $1-x\to x$.

Comment: @Ali Shather Thank you but ths is not the problem here. I have provided a nice expression for the integral above in $(4)$. The problem is to simplify $(5)$ as stated in my OP.

Comment: Got you. I dont think it can be more simplified. What I know of if that the polylog in (5) can be expressed in the integral you gave in (1) or in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^n H_n}{n^3}$.

Comment: By the way no need to use mathematica to get the integral in (1) , there is an easy way to get the closed form . I can provide the proof if you are interested.