# The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k k^{-3}/(2n-1)$

Tags: improper-integrals, divergent-series, cauchy-product

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{(2n-1)k^3}$$

Can anyone help me find this series? I tried to use Cauchy product but I don't know how I can complete it.

Comment: Your notation is confusing (to me, at least). What exactly does the $k=n$ over the second summation sign mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
\sum_{n = 1}^{k}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}k^{3}}} =
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3}}
\pars{\sum_{n = 1}^{2k}{1 \over n} -
\sum_{n = 1}^{k}{1 \over 2n}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k^{3}}\pars{H_{2k} - {1 \over 2}H_{k}} =
8\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{H_{2k} \over \pars{2k}^{3}} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{H_{k} \over k^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
8\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{H_{k} \over k^{3}}\,{1 + \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2} -
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{H_{k} \over k^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{7 \over 2}\ \underbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{H_{k} \over k^{3}}}
_{\ds{\color{#f00}{\S}:\ =\ {\pi^{4} \over 72}}} +
4\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{H_{k} \over k^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
{7 \over 144}\,\pi^{4} +
4\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{H_{k} \over k^{3}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

> $\ds{\color{#f00}{\S}}$: The sum was evaluated by Borwein &
>   Borwein-$\ds{1995}$. See $\ds{\pars{19}}$ in
>   [this link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html).

[I already evaluated the 'remaining sum'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2252705/85343) 
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{H_{k} \over k^{3}}}$ in a previous answer. Namely,
$$
\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k}\,{H_{k} \over k^{3}} =
-\,{11 \over 360}\,\pi^{4} - {1 \over 12}\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi^{2} +
{1 \over 12}\,\ln^{4}\pars{2} + 2\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1 \over 2} +
{7 \over 4}\,\ln\pars{2}\zeta\pars{3}
$$
such that \eqref{1} becomes:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{k}{1 \over \pars{2n - 1}k^{3}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\,{53 \over 720}\,\pi^{4} - {1 \over 3}\ln^{2}\pars{2}\pi^{2} +
{1 \over 3}\,\ln^{4}\pars{2} + 8\,\mrm{Li}_{4}\pars{1 \over 2} +
7\,\ln\pars{2}\zeta\pars{3}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 7):

We have:
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{x^{2k-1}}{2k-1}=\text{arctanh}(x),\qquad \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)x^{2k-1}=\frac{\text{arctanh}(x)}{1-x^2} $$
hence
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{2n-1}\right)\frac{1}{k^3}=4\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\text{arctanh}(x)\log^2(x)}{1-x^2}\,dx.$$
Can you compute the last integral? Hint: if you apply integration by parts, you are left with an integral related with $\int_{0}^{1}\text{arctanh}^2(x)\frac{\log x}{x}\,dx$. You may consider that
$$ \zeta(s) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^s} $$
through Laplace inverse transform takes the following integral representation:
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1}\,dx. $$
In the region $\text{Re}(s)>1$ we also have:
$$ \eta(s)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} = \left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right)\zeta(s), $$
but the abscissa of convergence of the series defining $\eta(s)$ is $\text{Re}(s)>0$. Given that, the analytic continuation of the $\zeta$ function to the half-plane $\text{Re}(s)>0$ is given by
$$\begin{eqnarray*}   \zeta(s) &=& \left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right)^{-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^s} \\ 
    (\text{through }\mathcal{L}^{-1})\quad &=& \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)}\left(1-\frac{2}{2^s}\right)^{-1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x+1}\,dx \\ 
    (\text{by parts})\quad &=& \frac{4^s}{2(2^s-2)\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^s\,dx}{\cosh^2(x)}\\ 
    (\text{by substitution})\quad &=&\color{red}{\frac{4^s}{2(2^s-2)\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{arctanh}(x)^s\,dx}\\ 
    &=& \frac{2^{s-1}}{(2^s-2)\Gamma(s+1)}\int_{0}^{1}\log^s\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\,dx.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
The original integral depends on the red integral at $s=2$. It follows (by Feynman's trick) that its closed form has the term $\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\zeta(3)$ and a term depending on $\zeta'(3)$.

---

Alternative approach: we want to compute $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{2n}-H_n/2}{n^3}$.
 Since $\sum_{n\geq 1}H_n x^n = -\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}$, we have:
$$\frac{\pi^4}{180}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{-\log(1-x)\log^2(x)}{1-x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{2H_n}{(n+1)^3}\tag{A}$$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_n}{2n^3}=\frac{\pi^4}{144}\tag{B}$$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{-\log(1-x)}{1-x}+\frac{-\log(1+x)}{1+x}\right)\frac{\log^2(x)}{x}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{H_{2n}}{2n^3}\\
=  -\frac{\pi ^4}{30}-\frac{\pi^2\log^2(2)}{6}+\frac{\log^4(2)}{6}+4 \text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{7\log(2)\zeta(3)}{2}\tag{C}$$

and:

$$\boxed{ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^3}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2m-1} = \color{red}{-\frac{53 \pi^4}{720}-\frac{\pi^2\log^2(2)}{3}+\frac{\log^4(2)}{3}+8\text{Li}_4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+7\log(2)\zeta(3)}}$$

Comment: But can you give me a hint to solve this improper integral?

Comment: @kaderezzat: dwell into dilogarithms, Feynman's trick, Euler's Beta function etcetera :D

Comment: Yes yes right,,,thanks alot this is a right answer

Comment: @kaderezzat: a small hint about the computation of the integral has been added.

Comment: Thanks alot you are number 1 in series and integrals mr jack

Comment: Sir can you complete the integral I tried to solve it but I'm not able to continue please

Comment: @kaderezzat: I added further details to my answer and showed the complete closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give another approach, you may consider that
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {\left( {2n - 1} \right)}}} {1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\left( {{1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {\left( {n - 1/2} \right)}}} } \right){1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\left( {{{\psi \left( {k + 1/2} \right) - \psi \left( {1/2} \right)} \over 2}} \right){1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{\gamma  \over 2} + \ln 2} \right)\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {{1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  + {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\psi \left( {k + 1/2} \right){1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {{\gamma  \over 2} + \ln 2} \right)\zeta (3) + {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\psi \left( {k + 1/2} \right){1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  \cr} 
$$

which computed numerically gives:
$$
S \approx 1.298176
$$

Also, we have
$$
\eqalign{
  & S = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,k\,} {\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {\left( {2n - 1} \right)}}} {1 \over {k^{\,3} }}}  = \sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\,} {{1 \over {\left( {2n - 1} \right)}}\sum\limits_{n\, \le \,k} {{1 \over {k^{\,3} }}} }  =   \cr 
  &  =  - {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\,} {{{\psi ^{\,\left( 2 \right)} \left( n \right)} \over {\left( {2n - 1} \right)}}}  =  - {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{1\, \le \,n\,} {{{\psi ^{\,\left( 2 \right)} \left( n \right)} \over {\left( {n - 1/2} \right)}}}  \cr} 
$$
which when computed numerically provides the same result.

However at present I did not succeed and profitably introduce in the 
sum above the integral representation for the polygamma functions.