# Proving that $~\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}~H_k~H_{k-1}=\frac{3}{16}~\zeta(4)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, contest-math, harmonic-numbers

To show that 
$$\sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{2}} \, \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{k}\right) \cdot \left(1+\frac{1}{2}+...+\frac{1}{k-1}\right) = \frac{3}{16}\zeta(4).$$

I came across this when trying to solve a problem from the current edition of the American Mathematical Monthly. Is there some easy way to show this? I checked numerically that this series does converge to the value of $\frac{3}{16}\zeta(4)$.

**Note**: An alternate form, with $H_{n}$ being the harmonic numbers, is:
$$ \sum\limits_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{2}} \, H_{k} \, H_{k-1} = \frac{3}{16}\zeta(4). $$

Comment: http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf has several techniques that might be useful, but I haven't finished reading it. Either way, it's a fun read :D

Comment: My go-to reference for this kind of stuff are the Borwein brothers. Check out this paper: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1995-123-04/S0002-9939-1995-1231029-X/S0002-9939-1995-1231029-X.pdf

specifically, the theorem and its corollaries under "Main Results" on page 2. My money is on manipulating the integral to give you that $H_kH_{k-1}$ combination. In particular check out the integrals that follow under equation (16) on page 7, which give the non-alternating sum version of your identity.

Comment: [Link for the AMM problem](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.124.7.659?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents). Here's an old [spoiler](http://zerocollar.blogspot.in/2015/05/alternating-version-of-au-yeung-series.html) blog post. But trust me, the problem in that form is much simpler than what I did in that blog. :P

Comment: @r9m impressive work!

Comment: @Alex Meiburg,@ Alex R: Thanks a lot for all the references, they are all very interesting. The link http://zerocollar.blogspot.in/2015/05/alternating-version-of-au-yeung-series.html shared by r9m pretty much solves it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is an opportunity to make a tribute to **Pieter J. de Doelder** (1919-1994) from Eindhoven University of Technology, who evaluated  in closed form the given series in a somewhat [famous paper (p. 132-133 2.3) (1991)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/037704279190112W/1-s2.0-037704279190112W-main.pdf?_tid=e15f61b2-7439-11e7-b04d-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1501317940_473eba781a2083b95aad438618a8717c). 
One may start by using the following identity coming from the Cauchy product,
$$
\ln^2(1+x) =2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n+1} \:x^{n+1}
$$ giving
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x} \:dx=2\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n}{n+1} \:\int_0^1 x^{n}\ln(1-x)\:dx,
$$ then using the standard evaluation
$$
\int_0^1 x^{n}\ln(1-x)\:dx =-\frac{H_{n+1}}{n+1},\quad n\ge0,
$$ one gets

> $$
> \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\:dx=2\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{H_n H_{n-1}}{n^{2}}. \tag1
> $$

Here are the main steps which de Doelder took to evaluate the related integral.

We clearly have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\ln^3\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\:\frac{dx}{x}&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1+x\right)}{x}\:dx-3\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\:dx
\\\\&+3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\:dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)}{x}\:dx
\end{align}
$$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x^2\right)}{x}\:dx&=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1+x\right)}{x}\:dx+3\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\:dx
\\\\&+3\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2(1-x)\ln(1+x)}{x}\:dx+\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)}{x}\:dx,
\end{align}
$$ substracting the two equalities,
$$
\begin{align}
6\!\!\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}dx&=\!\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x^2\right)}{x}dx-\!\int_0^1\!\!\ln^3\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}-2\!\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)}{x}dx
\\\\&=I_1-I_2-2I_3.
\end{align}
$$ It is easy to obtain
$$
\begin{align}
I_1=\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x^2\right)}{x}dx&=\frac12 \int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3\left(1-u\right)}{u}du \quad (u=x^2)
\\&=\frac12 \int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3 v}{1-v}dv \quad (v=1-u)
\\&=\frac12 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1\!v^n\ln^3 v\:dv 
\\&=-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1{n^4} 
\\&=-\frac{\pi^4}{30},
\end{align}
$$ similarly
$$
\begin{align}
I_3=\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3\left(1-x\right)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi^4}{15}.
\end{align}
$$ By the change of variable, $ u=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}$, one has $\dfrac{dx}{x}=\dfrac{-2\:du}{1-u^2}$ getting
$$
\begin{align}
I_2=\int_0^1\!\!\ln^3\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)\frac{dx}{x}&=-2\int_0^1\!\frac{\ln^3 u}{1-u^2}du 
\\&=-2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_0^1\!u^{2n}\ln^3u\:dv 
\\&=12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac1{(2n+1)^4} 
\\&=\frac{\pi^4}{8}.
\end{align}
$$ Then,

> $$
> \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)\ln^2(1+x)}{x}\:dx=-\frac{\pi^4}{240} \tag2
> $$

and

> $$
> \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{H_n H_{n-1}}{n^{2}}= \frac{3}{16}\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{480},\tag3
> $$

as announced.

Comment: thanks! This integral is exactly the problem proposed in AMM this month.  Would it be wrong to publicly keep this solution up here in that case?

Comment: (+1) Nice solution .. !! :) Elementary and elegant as usual!

Comment: @Aritro Pathak You are welcome! It's no big deal, this monthly problem is *not* original, it is known for years.

Comment: Ingenious! Regarding the question of motivation for the solution, I suppose you do have to memorize identities like the first and third, is that right?

Comment: @Hans Right, and if you don't memorize it, you know it does exist somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: All is working fine because $(a+b)^3-(a-b)^3=2b^3+6a^2b$

Answer (score 8):

Although I have seen too few proofs in this field to be able to compare, this approach might be interesting.

We transform the sum to a fourfold integral which Mathematica can solve immediately. I hope it should be possible to solve the integral "mathematically" as well, which would then complete the proof.

We have to calculate

$$s=\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^k}{k^2} H(k) H(k-1) $$

Writing

$$\frac{1}{n^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x}\,dx \int_0^x y^{n-1} \, dy $$

$$\frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 r^{n-1} \, dr$$

and

$$H(k)=\sum _{n=1}^k \frac{1}{n}=\int_0^1 \left(\sum _{n=1}^k r^{n-1}\right) \, dr=\int_0^1 \frac{1-r^k}{1-r} \, dr$$

the sum $s$ below the integrals becomes

$$si=\frac{1}{x(1-r)(1-s)}\sum _{k=2}^{\infty } (-1)^k \left(1-r^k\right) \left(1-s^{k-1}\right) y^{k-1}$$

Which evaluates to

$$si = \frac{y \left(r^2 s^2 y+r^2 s-r^2 y-r^2-r s^2 y+r y-s+1\right)}{(1-r) (1-s) x (y+1) (r y+1) (s y+1) (r s y+1)}$$

Now the integral to be evaluated is

$$s4 = \int _0^1 dx\int _0^x dy\int _0^1 dr\int _0^1 ds \; si$$

Mathematica finds immediately

$$s4 = \frac{\pi ^4}{480} $$

Since

$$\zeta (4)=\frac{\pi ^4}{90}$$

and

$$\frac{90}{480} = \frac{3}{16} $$

we have finally

$$s = \frac{3}{16} \zeta(4)$$

Comment: Thank you for this point of view! (+1) Is it possible to have a screenshot of your instructions in *Mathematica*? Thanks.

Comment: @Olivier Oloa No screenshot necessary. Using the integrand $si$ as defined above it's just this statement Integrate[si, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, x}, {r, 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}]. To my big surprise the result pi^4/480 was returned within a second. So if I had not known the result in advance I would have found it heuristically. This is not replacing a strict proof, of course.

Comment: Maple can't integrate, so it's not that trivial ;-(

Comment: @Diger I have never used maple but did you try different versions of maple? I keep several older versions of Mathematica because some are better in integrating than others.

Comment: Unfortunately not; just tried 2018.

Comment: Have you tried RUBI? I think it is only for Mathematica, or?

Comment: @Diger No, I confine myself to pure Mathematica which is sufficient for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

**Bonus**

$$S=\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}H_kH_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k^2}H_kH_{k-1}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kH_k^2}{k^2}-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kH_k}{k^3}$$

Since $S=\frac3{16}\zeta(4)$ and [$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^kH_k}{k^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k/3219475#3219475) $=2\operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{11}4\zeta(4)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{12}\ln^42$

then

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^kH_k^2}{k^2}=2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac12\right)-\frac{41}{16}\zeta(4)+\frac74\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac12\ln^22\zeta(2)+\frac1{12}\ln^42$$