# Is there closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(4)}}{k^2}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, harmonic-numbers

Do we have closed form for

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(4)}}{k^2}\ ?$$

where $H_k$ is the harmonic number.

I encountered this sum while I was working on calculating $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{(2k+1)^4}$ and I found using Abel's summation that

> $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_k^{(2)}}{(2k+1)^4}+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(4)}}{k^2}=\frac{31}{16}\zeta^2(3)-\frac{13}{3}\zeta(6)$$

If the reader is curious about how I got this relation, I just followed the same approach [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3259984).

I am familiar with $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{H_k^{(4)}}{k}$ but not the $\displaystyle \frac1{k^2}$ version.

---

Here is the integral representation of each

Knowing that

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k^{(2)}x^k=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{1-x}$$

Replace $x$ with $x^2$ and multiply both sides by $-\frac16\ln^3x$ then $\int_0^1$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{(2n+1)^4}=-\frac16\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_2(x^2)\ln^3x}{1-x^2}\ dx$$

For the other sum , use

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty H_k^{(4)}x^k=\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(x)}{1-x}$$

Replace $x$ with $-x$ and multiply both sides by $-\frac{\ln x}{x}$ then $\int_0^1$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k \frac{H_k^{(4)}}{k^2}=-\int_0^1\frac{\operatorname{Li}_4(-x)\ln x}{x(1+x)}\ dx$$

Comment: +1 I like lots of your questions and answers Ali. Keep posting.

Comment: @Isham Thank you for the kind words and the encouragement.

Comment: $$4 \zeta(\bar5,1)-\frac{3 \zeta (3)^2}{4}-\frac{17 \pi ^6}{25920}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of known constants such as $\pi$, $\ln 2$, or function values of the Riemann zeta function $\zeta (x)$ or the polylogarithm $\operatorname{Li}_s (x)$, the answer seems to be no. The reason for this is it can be shown that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H^{(4)}_n}{n^2} = 4 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H_n}{n^5} + 2 \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n H^{(2)}_n}{n^4} - \frac{9}{16} \zeta^2 (3) + \frac{359}{64} \zeta (6),$$
and it is well-known that the alternating Euler sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n H_n/n^5$ has no closed form in terms of the known constants I mentioned above.

Comment: I agree with you. By the way I think your result follows from Cauchy product by which we have 

$$\operatorname{Li}_4(x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_3^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n\left(\frac{2H_n}{n^5}+\frac{2H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+\frac{2H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}+\frac{2H_n^{(4)}}{n^2}-\frac{10}{n^6}\right)$$

now we set $x=-1$. Thank you for your efforts (+1)

Comment: @AliShadhar Very nice identity, could you share some sources\lists with nice identities obtained by Cauchy product involving polylogarithms? Aside from Cornels book.