# Show the integral identity $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) (\ln(1+x))^2}{x} dx = -\frac{\pi^4}{240}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

> Show that 
>   \begin{eqnarray*}
> I_2=\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1-x) (\ln(1+x))^2}{x} dx = -\frac{\pi^4}{240}.
> \end{eqnarray*}

Motivation: I am actually interested in triple plums of the form 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{ (-1)^{\star}}{ijk(i+j+k)}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\star$ is $0,i,i+j$ of $i+j+k$. (So with $\star=i+j$ we have the above integral.

My try to solve the problem:

It is easy to show (sub $y=1-x$, geometrically expand the denominator and integrate term by term)
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_0=\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(1-x))^3 }{x} dx = -6\zeta(4)= -\frac{\pi^4}{15}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Now look at Ali's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251069/nice-two-related-sums-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-n2n2-and-sum) to see that:
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_1 =\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(1-x))^2 \ln(1+x)}{x} dx = -\frac{5}{8}\zeta(4)+2 \left( \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)+\frac78\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac14(\ln 2)^2\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{24} (\ln 2)^4 \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Next use [Wolfie](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int((ln(1%2Bx))%5E3%2Fx,%7Bx,0,1%7D)) to get:
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_3 =\int_0^1 \frac{ (\ln(1+x))^3}{x} dx = 6\zeta(4)-6 \left( \operatorname{Li_4}\left(\frac12\right)+\frac{7}{8}\ln2\zeta(3)-\frac14(\ln 2)^2\zeta(2)+\frac{1}{24} (\ln 2)^4 \right).
\end{eqnarray*}

Finally consider the following linear combination of the above integrals
\begin{eqnarray*}
I_0+3I_1+3I_2+I_3= \int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(1-x^2))^3 }{x} dx = \frac{1}{2} I_0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now just do the linear algebra & we are dumb.

So my question is: Is there an easier way that manages to avoid the fourth polylogarithm of a laugh?