# Closed form for $\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_3(-x)\mathrm{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

I am looking for a closed form for: 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\mathrm{Li}_3(-x)\mathrm{Li}_2(x)}{x}\ \mathrm{d}x.$$
I am assuming integration by parts multiple times but I can't get anywhere with it. Any help/ hint would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_0^1\frac{\text{Li}_3(-x)\text{Li}_2(x)}{x}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\text{Li}_2(x)dx$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n^3}\left(\frac{\zeta(2)}{n}-\frac{H_n}{n^2}\right)$$

$$=\zeta(2)\text{Li}_4(-1)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}$$

$$=-\frac{49}{28}\zeta(6)-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^nH_n}{n^5}$$

Unfortunately there is no known closed form for the latter sum.

Comment: Do you think we will be able to find a closed form for the latter sum any time soon?

Comment: And is this the case for many of the alternating harmonic sums involving an odd exponent? For example $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n^3}$? These seem particularly interesting...

Comment: What I know of that there is no closed form for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n^a}$ for $a=5,7,...$.

Comment: So there is a closed form for $a=3$? If so, has it been found?

Comment: Yep, you can find it evaluated here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457371/alternating-harmonic-sum-sum-k-geq-1-frac-1kk3h-k/3219475#3219475

Answer (score 2):

A conjectural evaluation for the remaining alternating sum is given in equation (19) of https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.04770, namely
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_{n-1}}{n^5}
= \frac{1}{13} \left( \frac{1}{3}\operatorname{Li}_6\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right) - 162 \operatorname{Li}_6\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) - 126 \operatorname{Li}_6\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) \right)
-\frac{1787}{624} \zeta(6) + \frac{3}{8} \zeta(3)^2
\\
+\frac{31}{16}\zeta(5) \log(2) - \frac{15}{26} \zeta(4) \log^2(2) + \frac{3}{104} \zeta(2) \log^4(2) - \frac{1}{208} \log^6(2)
$$
Subtract this from $-\frac{9}{16} \zeta(6)$ to get the answer for the original question. Note the relation
$$
\int_0^1 \frac{\operatorname{Li}_3(-x)\operatorname{Li}_2(x)}{x} \mathrm{d} x
= -\frac{9}{16} \zeta(6) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_{n-1}}{n^5}
= -\frac{49}{32} \zeta(6) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n H_{n}}{n^5}
$$
where the denominator in the coefficient of $\zeta(6)$ in the above answer is corrected, the $-\frac{49}{28} \zeta(6)$ there should read $-\frac{49}{32}\zeta(6)$.

Comment: Wow! This is the first conjecture I have seen of that sum. Is there any note on how it was achieved?

Comment: If the conjecture is indeed correct, then many integrals on this site involving $\sum_{n\geqslant 1} \frac{H_n}{n^52^n}$ may be computed.

Comment: Can you mention the page number and equation number of this sum please?

Comment: As I wrote, it's equation (19). That appears on page 22.

Comment: Also, the only conjectural part is the coefficient of Zeta(6). That is, it is a theorem that the identity holds for some rational factor in front of Zeta(6) (all other coefficients are proven). The coefficient of Zeta(6) was fixed numerically.

Comment: The proof uses quite abstract machinery (motivic periods). It would be great if anyone would find an elementary proof!