# How find this integral $I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln{(1+\tan^4{x})})^2\frac{2\cos^2{x}}{2-(\sin{(2x)})^2}dx$

Tags: integration

> Find the value:
>
> $$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}(\ln{(1+\tan^4{x})})^2\dfrac{2\cos^2{x}}{2-(\sin{(2x)})^2}dx$$

I use computer have this  reslut

$$I=-\dfrac{4\pi}{\sqrt{2}}C+\dfrac{13\pi^3}{24\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{9}{2}\dfrac{\pi\ln^2{2}}{\sqrt{2}}-\dfrac{3}{2}\dfrac{\pi^2\ln{2}}{\sqrt{2}}$$

where $C$ is Catalan constant.

My idea: let $$\tan{x}=t,\sin{2x}=\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},dx=\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}$$

then
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln^2{(1+t^4)}\dfrac{\dfrac{2}{1+t^2}}{2-\left(\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2}\right)^2}\cdot\dfrac{dt}{1+t^2}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln^2{(1+t^4)}}{(t^2-1)^2}dt$$

Then I can't.Thank you

Comment: Theon is right : it should be $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\ln^2{(1+t^4)}}{1+t^4}dt$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an approach. I'll continue from the step you have already reached with the correction suggested in Fabien comment which is considering the integral

> $$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2(1+x^4)}{1+x^4} dx. $$

To evaluate the above integral we consider the integral

$$ F = \int_{0}^{\infty} (1+x^4)^{\alpha} dx = \frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{2}\Gamma( 3/4 )}{\frac {\Gamma  ( -1/4-\alpha ) }{
\Gamma  \left( -\alpha \right)  }},$$

which can be evaluated using the [beta function techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/270118/a-few-improper-integral/270124#270124) (use the substitution $(1+x^4)=\frac{1}{t}$). Now $I$ follows from $F$ as (see [related techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290250/show-that-int-0-pi-2-frac-log2-sin-x-log2-cos-x-cos-x-sin-x-mathrm/291975#291975) )

> $$ I = \lim_{\alpha \to -1}\frac{d^2F(\alpha)}{d\alpha^2}=\frac{\pi \,\sqrt {2}}{48}\left({\pi}^{2}-36\,\pi \,\ln  \left( 2 \right) +108 \ln^2( 2 )+12\,\psi'\left( 3/4 \right)  \right) .$$

Comment: +1. The substitution which leads to the Beta function should be $\displaystyle{\large\left(1 + x^{4}\right) \equiv {1 \over t}}$. I guess that's is a typo. Otherwise, it's a straightforward answer.

Comment: @FelixMarin: It is a typo. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $\quad~I(n)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\Big(1+x^k\Big)^n~dx\quad~=>\quad~I''(-1)~=~\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^2\big(1+x^k\big)}{1+x^k}~dx.~$ But, at

the same time, $I(n)$ can be shown to [equal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) $~\dfrac1k\cdot B\bigg(\dfrac1k~,-\dfrac1k-n\bigg),~$ with the help of the simple

substitution $t=\dfrac1{1+x^k}$ . Then, expressing it in terms of the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), differentiating, and

using the relationship between the [polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Recurrence_relation) $\psi_0$ and [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation), along with

Euler's formula for their generalization to non-natural arguments, we are thus finally able to

arrive at an expression whose only “mysterious” quantity is $\psi_{_1}\Big(\frac34\Big).~$ Since this function has

been studied for several centuries, I'm sure you will be able to find its closed form expression

somewhere, along with the proof behind it. Also, Euler's [reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties)

might be of some assistance.

Comment: Personally, i believe this is how answers are ought to be written.

Comment: Really nice answer : the maths for the result isn't necessary, the way of thinking is what matters.

Answer (score 2):

After performing the initial arctangent substitution, the resultant integral may be rewritten as the second derivative of a beta function and evaluated accordingly:

$$\begin{align}
I
&=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\cos^2{\theta}}{2-\sin^2{(2\theta)}}\log^2{\left(1+\tan^4{\theta}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}\theta\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^2{(1+x^4)}}{1+x^4}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\bigg{|}_{\alpha=1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^4)^{\alpha}}\\
&=\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\bigg{|}_{\alpha=1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\frac14u^{-\frac34}}{(1+u)^{\alpha}}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac14\frac{d^2}{d\alpha^2}\bigg{|}_{\alpha=1}\operatorname{B}{\left(\frac14,\alpha-\frac14\right)}\\
&=\frac14\Gamma{\left(\frac14\right)}\Gamma{\left(\frac34\right)}\left[-\zeta{(2)}+\left(\gamma+\Psi{\left(\frac34\right)}\right)^2+\Psi^\prime{\left(\frac34\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{\sqrt{2}\,\pi}{4}\left[-\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\log{8}\right)^2+\pi^2-8C\right]\\
&=-2\sqrt{2}\,\pi\,C+\frac{13\pi^3}{24\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\pi\log^2{8}}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\pi^2\log{8}}{2\sqrt{2}}.~~~\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have made a mistake with the denominator, which cannot be zero. See, $2-sin(2x)^2$ is always bigger or equal than $1$.

I think that the mistake was in expanding $2-(\frac{2t}{1+t^2})^2$: you have changed that initial $2$ for a $1$ and then completed the square.  Repeat that expansion slowly.