# Alternating Euler sums

Tags: integration, summation, harmonic-numbers

$ \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{(n-1)} \frac{{\rm H}_n}{n^p} $

Does this have a nice closed form? I am trying to evaluate the case of p=4 also

Comment: Recall that $H_n$ are harmonic numbers.

Comment: Have a look at (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/457371)

Comment: I have the p=3 case. Lookibg forward to the 4 th power case. The integrations are quite complex.

Comment: I advise you, for another time, to make a prior web search and indicate through the relevant site(s) what is the degree of knowledge you have about the issue at hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> In *[Euler Sums and Contour Integral Representations](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/FlSa98.pdf)* by P. Flajolet and B. Salvy they state in Theorem 7.1 (Sitaramachandra Rao) for odd weight $q+1$:
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^q}
> &=\frac{q+1}{2}\left(1-2^{-q}\right)\zeta(q+1)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(q+1)\\
> &\qquad-\sum_{k=1}^{q/2-1}\left(1-2^{1-2k}\right)\zeta(2k)\zeta(q+1-2k)
> \end{align*}

We  obtain for odd  $q+1=5$:

> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_n}{n^4}
> &=\frac{5}{2}\left(1-2^{-4}\right)\zeta(5)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(5)\
> -\left(1-2^{-1}\right)\zeta(2)\zeta(3)\\
> &=\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\zeta(3)
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution to the case $p=4$ that can be extended to all values, $p=2m, \ m\ge1$, may be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3269815.